# Building and running app via Gradle and Android Studio is slower than via Eclipse

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

I have a multi-project (~10 modules) of which building takes about 20-30 seconds each time. When I press Run in Android Studio, I have to wait every time to rebuild the app, which is extremely slow.

Is it possible to automate building process in Android Studio? Or do you have any advice on how to make this process faster?

In Eclipse, thanks to automatic building, running the same project on an emulator takes about 3-5 seconds.

This is my build.gradle file (app module):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':libraries:SharedLibs')
    compile project(':libraries:actionbarsherlock')
    compile project(':libraries:FacebookSDK')
    compile project(':libraries:GooglePlayServices')
    compile project(':libraries:HorizontalGridView')
    compile project(':libraries:ImageViewTouch')
    compile project(':libraries:SlidingMenu')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

Comment: Please bear in mind that neither the Gradle-based build system nor Android Studio are production-grade at this time.

Comment: The time being spent here is most likely in the DEXing phase. Unfortunately, android studio's make seems to perform a clean every single time, causing the previously dex'd files to be deleted. Hopefully, we'll see an incremental build fix soon.

Comment: In the meantime, is there any simple way of telling changing the default Gradle tasks such that they do not always perform a clean?

Comment: @CommonsWare well,  there is no excuse now we are on version 1.02, but its still a major issue. With Android studio running my 4GB quad core laptop uses about 3.75gb of its ram just holding a single instance of a hello world project. It is also as a result very sluggish. To me that indicates a serious and on going design flaw.  I hope things are resolved soon.

Comment: @AndrewS: My 8GB quad-core Ubuntu notebook only needs 518MB of RAM for Android Studio, with a "hello, world"-sized project open, a complete build of the project, and running it on an emulator (emulator is a separate 310MB, and what I believe is the Gradle daemon another separate 310MB). Perhaps there is something amiss with your installation.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the reply. Interesting does this indicate a problem with the way Android studio runs under a windows environment? I say this because with just a browser with 5 tabs open and Android studio pushes it up to 3.75. On closing Android studio memory consumption drops to  between 1.4 and 1.6gb.  I'm guessing if I launched it on a Linux box, I'd get the same performance benefits then? Are you taking into account that Android studio also causes Java.exe to run a an extremely high memory load, so alone might not look that bad?

Comment: @AndrewS: "does this indicate a problem with the way Android studio runs under a windows environment?" -- beats me. I don't run Windows much. "On closing Android studio memory consumption drops to between 1.4 and 1.6gb" -- that should also shut down the Gradle daemon, if I understand Android Studio's behavior correctly. "Are you taking into account that Android studio also causes Java.exe to run a an extremely high memory load, so alone might not look that bad? -- yes.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok thanks for that information. Looks like I may need to change my OS.

Comment: @AndrewS I find it a pity we need to change our OS just to get gradle to run at a reasonable speed compared to the previous tools.

Comment: @Richard Le Mesurier . I agree. In fact I had to upgrade my own PC significantly to the tune of 600 dollars. Now with High Spec Core i7, 16gb or ram and an SSD hard drive do I get the kind of 'enhanced' performance I expect from shiny new so called 'better' development tools.

Comment: i upgraded ram from 4gb to 8gb and now taking 50 seconds instead of 54 seconds previously, saved my four seconds each time

Comment: You should see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58754073/1677824

Answer (score 445, accepted):

### Hardware

I'm sorry, but upgrading development station to SSD and tons of ram has probably a bigger influence than points below combined.

### Tools versions

Increasing build performance has major priority for the development teams, so make sure you are using latest [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/release-notes) and [Android Gradle Plugin](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system).

### Configuration File

Create a file named `gradle.properties` in whatever directory applies:

- `/home/<username>/.gradle/` (Linux)
- `/Users/<username>/.gradle/` (Mac)
- `C:\Users\<username>\.gradle` (Windows)

Append:

```
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Settings specified in this file will override any Gradle settings
# configured through the IDE.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# The Gradle daemon aims to improve the startup and execution time of Gradle.
# When set to true the Gradle daemon is to run the build.
# TODO: disable daemon on CI, since builds should be clean and reliable on servers
org.gradle.daemon=true

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# https://medium.com/google-developers/faster-android-studio-builds-with-dex-in-process-5988ed8aa37e#.krd1mm27v
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx5120m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
org.gradle.parallel=true

# Enables new incubating mode that makes Gradle selective when configuring projects. 
# Only relevant projects are configured which results in faster builds for large multi-projects.
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:configuration_on_demand
org.gradle.configureondemand=true

# Set to true or false to enable or disable the build cache. 
# If this parameter is not set, the build cache is disabled by default.
# http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/build-cache
android.enableBuildCache=true
```

Gradle properties works local if you place them at `projectRoot\gradle.properties` and globally if you place them at `user_home\.gradle\gradle.properties`. Properties applied if you run gradle tasks from console or directly from idea:

### IDE Settings

It is possible to tweak Gradle-IntelliJ integration from the IDE settings GUI. Enabling "offline work" (check answer from [yava](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23648341/624706) below) will disable real network requests on every "sync gradle file".

[image: IDE settings]

### Native multi-dex

One of the slowest steps of the apk build is converting java bytecode into single dex file. Enabling native multidex (minSdk 21 for debug builds only) will help the tooling to reduce an amount of work (check answer from [Aksel Willgert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30070657/624706) below).

### Dependencies

Prefer `@aar` dependencies over library sub-projects.

Search aar package on [mavenCentral](http://search.maven.org/), [jCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter) or use [jitpack.io](https://jitpack.io/) to build any library from github. If you are not editing sources of the dependency library you should not build it every time with your project sources.

### Antivirus

Consider to exclude project and cache files from antivirus scanning. This is obviously a trade off with security (don't try this at home!). But if you switch between branches a lot, then antivirus will rescan files before allowing gradle process to use it, which slows build time (in particular AndroidStudio sync project with gradle files and indexing tasks). Measure build time and process CPU with and without antivirus enabled to see if it is related.

### Profiling a build

Gradle has built-in support for [profiling projects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html#sec:profiling_build). Different projects are using a different combination of plugins and custom scripts. Using `--profile` will help to find bottlenecks.

Comment: about @aar depedencies: using e.g `dependencies {compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'}` is a slow solution? not sure to understand

Comment: Imaging, you have added library like this one: https://github.com/novak/numberpicker. It has value, providing code solution  for a problem, but author doesn't published it anywhere like maven or jCenter. Now you are either bring that library as sources into your project and build it everytime main project builds or compile it onetime and commit only @aar into your project repository. So it is really a source/binary dependency choice. If you are not editing source you should bring your dependency as precompiled binary. For plain java libraries that is .jar, for android libraries that is .aar

Comment: "*Don't use auto-import feature (yet)*" > Can you explain where this feature is enabled/disabled in Android Studio? I'm not 100% sure what you're referring to.

Comment: It's project settings > gradle. See screenshot below: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wrwgo.png

Comment: I've setup all optimizations as described, however in Android Studio it takes 3 to 4 minutes to start my app, whereas it was about 30 seconds in Eclipse. Crap. Only 12 projects, one single app to run! Android dev has become so cumbersome now, and that's more than a year later.

Comment: I applied all optimizations and it still takes around 20 seconds to build a HelloWorld apk, compared to 2-3 seconds in Eclipse.

Comment: Why don't you use Eclipse then? Why do we comparing build system with IDE? Gradle is about features and possibilities for the developer. Performance is just one feature of it. Try to setup Ant (I assume you use Ant with Eclipse) to handle all the cases which Gradle build can handle and lets compare how much time will it takes. Gradle, Ant, Maven, Buck, Bazel, Sbt there are enough choices for the android dev these days.

Comment: @3c71, have you fixed your issue? I'm on the same boat, 1 app, 3 projects  and it takes 2~3

Comment: @HenriquedeSousa, unfortunately not. I upgraded to latest AS (from canary channel), latest gradle beta (1.3b3 I think), it's driving me crazy. This issue tracker does help somehow, but has other drawbacks: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=80272. Using such, I managed to drop the build time to 45 seconds, unfortunately I have to run it twice for all dependencies to be updated properly :(

Comment: We've found out the issue: it was retrolambda which was forcing to build everything (so there was no advantage in incrmental builds). After removing retrolambda the problem was solved. Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: @HenriquedeSousa Why couldn't you have put some kind of a better description of "removing retrolambda" in an answer for others to access?

Comment: Indeed, you should have done it in the first place. I followed your advice and answered it. Thanks.

Comment: Well , Its slow down more then ever after follow this steps . Android studio sucks !!

Comment: which plugins to disable?

Comment: The parameter `--daemon` no longer exists. You can still use the config file to obtain daemon behavior.

Comment: Nothing says competent Windows port like dotfiles in your top-level user directory.

Comment: I am poor and code for food and live on the slum with a shittiest internet. This solution doesn't apply to me. Sad....

Comment: I'd like to add the following to the Hardware section: RAM is essential, and 16GB is my minimum now. Having worked in 3 large-sized projects (for reference: +200 classes at ~500 LOC, play services, guava, and/or other "heavy" dependencies), I noted RAM upgrade, particularly the 8GB to 16GB jump, has drastic effect - think 10min to 30s. Also, this disparate performance difference was noted both on SSD'd, I7 machines under both Windows and Linux, running my usual workspace stuff (20tabs Chromium, HQ Spotify, random TextEditor and a CLI/Putty/SSH or two on the side idling around)

Comment: Native multidexing is enabled by default so long as you're running the latest (at this time 3.1) version of android studio and you're running on a device with api level 21 or higher. Android studio runs + installs will automatically pass the api level to the build process and enable native multi dexing as appropriate.

Comment: To the author, about `TODO: disable daemon on CI, since builds should be clean and reliable on servers` consider read: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2824

Answer (score 150):

You can ignore gradle update-to-date checks.

[image]

For Windows running Android Studio 1.5: Go to `File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build tools -> Gradle -> Check Offline work (as shown in image)`

down from ~30+ sec to ~3 sec

Comment: Thats pretty cool. That is a LOT faster. But what does this break?

Comment: Best solution. Can i know the side effects of this solution

Comment: @JohnBallinger Offline work - use this check box to work with Gradle in the offline mode. In this case Gradle will use dependencies from the cache. Gradle will not attempt to access the network to perform dependency resolution. If required dependencies are not present in the dependencies' cache, a build execution will fail. (Source: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/gradle-2.html)

Comment: Does it default to use cached dependencies first before going over the network? I can't imagine this checks for updated dependencies everytime `gradle` is run. That's bizarre.

Comment: @EhteshChoudhury it's VERY bizarre. The whole Gradle/Android Studio dev environment is so slooooooow. Most people think it's slow because of Java. I do server side Java dev on IDEA and things run very smoothly.

Comment: This reduces my build time from minutes to seconds.. thanks

Answer (score 35):

Searched everywhere for this and finally found a solution that works for us. Enabling parallel builds (On OSX: `preferences -> compiler -> gradle -> "Compile independent modules in parallel"`) and enabling 'make project automatically' brought it down from ~1 min to ~20 sec. Thanks to /u/Covalence.

http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/1k3nb3/gradle_and_android_studio_way_slower_to_build/

Comment: Keep in mind this apparently only helps when you have multiple independent modules/projects. I've tested it out on a single module app, and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: I have a pretty big project and it takes 2 - 3 minutes on MacBook Pro 2012 Core i7, 8 GB RAM. Is it ok?

Answer (score 25):

I recently bought a new SSD and went from Windows to Linux.My build times are now an order of magnitude faster, and no longer annoying.

Though it does not directly answer your question as to why it's slower than eclipse, it shows that the process is disk-bounded and an upgrade to an SSD might be a (somewhat expensive) solution. I'm guessing there will be people googling the issue and ending up here, who might appreciate my experience.

Comment: The developers on my team have fast SSDs in fast machines with lots of memory.  For a non-trivial app, redeploying after a minor code change still takes about ~45 seconds, compared to re-deploying almost instantly in Eclipse.  Even running a plain, non-Android JUnit is prohibitively slow.  "Upgrading" to Android Studio and Gradle has been a big downgrade so far.  :-/

Comment: @Lionleaf how much faster switching from windows to linux?

Comment: @younes0 I do not know. I switched to Linux at the same time I switched to an SSD. I'm not saying it has any positive effect, it was just those two variables I changed for the speedup.

Comment: In my case switching from Windows to Linux resulted in 40% faster Android builds... so it's definitely worth it

Comment: I second what @Bartosz Kosarzycki said. I ended up running an Ubuntu vm with virtualbox on my dev machine. ~54 second build on windows, ~7sec for the same build inside the virtual machine on the same hardware. Insane speedup by moving to Linux.

Answer (score 21):

**Speed Up Gradle Build In Android Studio 3.2.1**

Ever feel like you are waiting for the builds to complete in Android Studio for minutes? Me too. And it’s a pretty annoying.
Fortunately, there are a few ways that you can use to improve this. Android uses Gradle for building. The latest version is 4.6 has a huge performance boost over previous versions (see Release notes for details).

**Step 1:** Update Gradle version
An easier way to accomplish this is to go to: Open Module Settings (your project) > Project Structure

[image]

**UPDATE**

Change to **Gradle version: 4.6**
and
Change to **Android Plugin Version: 3.2.1**

[image]

Download Gradle Release distributive from [https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip)
And copy it to the Gradle folder:

[image]

Last step is to add your discribution in Settings > Gradle

[image]

Don’t forget to click Apply to save changes.

**Step 2:** Enable Offline mode, Gradle daemon and parallel build for the project
Offline mode tells Gradle to ignore update-to-date checks. Gradle asks for dependencies everytime and having this option makes it just uses what is already on the machine for dependencies.
Go to Gradle from android studio Setting and click in Offline work box.

[image]

2. Go to Compiler from android studio Setting and add “— offline” in command-line box and click Compile independent modules in parallel.

[image]

The next step is to enable the Gradle daemon and parallel build for your project. Parallel builds will cause your projects with multiple modules (multi-project builds in Gradle) to be built in parallel, which should make large or modular projects build faster.

[image]

These settings could enabled by modifiing a file named gradle.properties in Gradle scripts directory(i.e., ~/.gradle/gradle.properties).Some of these options (e.g. Complie modules in parallel) are available from Android Studio and also enabled there by default, but putting them in the gradle.properties file will enabled them when building from the terminal and also making sure that your colleagues will use the same settings. But if you’re working on a team, sometimes you can’t commit this stuff.

```
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit org.gradle.parallel=true
# When set to true the Gradle daemon is used to run the build. For local developer builds this is our favorite property.
# The developer environment is optimized for speed and feedback so we nearly always run Gradle jobs with the daemon.
 org.gradle.daemon=true
```

Using the daemon will make your builds startup faster as it won’t have to start up the entire Gradle application every time. The Gradle Daemon is not enabled by default, but it’s recommend always enabling it for developers’ machines (but leaving it disabled for continuous integration servers). FAQ about this mode could be found here https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
The parallel builds setting could be unsafe for some projects. The requirement is that all your modules must be decoupled or your build could fail (see http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects for details).

**Step 3:** Enable incremental dexign and tweak memory settings
You can speed up your builds by turning on incremental dexing. In your module’s build file:

[image]

Add this option to your android block:

```
dexOptions {
    incremental true
}
```

In that dexOptions block you can also specify the heap size for the dex process, for example:

```
dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "12g"
}
```

Where “12g” is 12GB of memory. Additional information about this could be found here google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/
You can also configure Gradle parameters in the settings file, e.g. increase the max heap size in case you have a large project:

```
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

See all list of parameters here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties for details.

**Step 4:** Disable Antivirus
Consider to exclude project and cache files from antivirus scanning. This is obviously a trade off with security. But if you switch between branches a lot, then antivirus will rescan files before allowing gradle process to use it, which slows build time (in particular Android Studio sync project with gradle files and indexing tasks). Measure build time and process CPU with and without antivirus enabled to see if it is related.
I hope this helps. Leave a comment if you have any question or some other tips for improving the build performance.

[helpful link](https://medium.com/@101/speed-up-gradle-build-in-android-studio-80a5f74ac9ed#.vm894p5iz)

Answer (score 19):

If using google play services, depending on just the libraries you need instead of the whole blob can make things faster.

If your only need is maps, use:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.+'
```

instead of:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'
```

The latter brings 20k methods [(see blog)](http://jakewharton.com/play-services-is-a-monolith/) into the classpath, which might tip the total method count over 64k.

That would force the use of proguard or [multidex](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html) even for debug builds. For one of my projects i had the following build times

- multidex build (with supportlibrary) ~40sec
- proguard build ~20sec
- build when method limit < 64k ~5sec

If developing on sdk 21+, it would possible to optimize multidex builds as stated [in the android documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#dev-build)

```
android {
    productFlavors {
        // Define separate dev and prod product flavors.
        dev {
            // dev utilizes minSDKVersion = 21 to allow the Android gradle plugin
            // to pre-dex each module and produce an APK that can be tested on
            // Android Lollipop without time consuming dex merging processes.
            minSdkVersion 21
        }
        prod {
            // The actual minSdkVersion for the application.
            minSdkVersion 14
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Instead of compiling all the `play-service` library, I compiled only `maps` and `locations`  and disabled the `multidex`. I feel the big difference. Thanks  +1

Answer (score 16):

The accepted answer is for older versions of android studio and most of them works still now. Updating android studio made it a little bit faster. Don't bother to specify heap size as it'll increase automatically with the increase of Xms and Xmx. Here's some modification with the VMoptions

1. In bin folder there's a studio.vmoptions file to set the environment configuration. In my case this is studio64.vmoptions
   Add the following lines if they're not added already and save the file. In my case I've 8GB RAM.

   ```
   -Xms4096m
   -Xmx4096m
   -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
   -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
   -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled 
   -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
   -Dfile.encoding=utf-8`
   ```
2. Start android studio. Go to File-> Settings-> Build, Execution, Deployment-> Compiler

   - Check compile independent modules in parallel
   - In command-line Options write: --offline
   - Check Make project automatically
   - Check configure on demand

In case of using mac, at first I couldn't find the vmoptions. Anyway, here's a [nice article about how we can change the vmoptions in MAC OSX](http://lifeofcoding.com/2015/01/19/How-to-increase-Android-studio-memory-limit-in-Mac/). Quoting from this article here.

Open your terminal and put this command to open the vmoptions in MAC OSX:

```
open -e /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions
```

Comment: as of AS 2.3.2 you can change vim options by help-> Edit Custom Vm Options

Answer (score 15):

Just create a file named gradle.properties in the following directory:

```
/home/<username>/.gradle/ (Linux)
/Users/<username>/.gradle/ (Mac)
C:\Users\<username>\.gradle (Windows)
```

Add this line to the file:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
```

For me the speed is now equal to Eclipse.

Source: https://www.timroes.de/2013/09/12/speed-up-gradle/

Comment: I am not able to see .gradle folder in mac. How to open it?

Comment: @Dharmik: Maybe you have installed Android Studio under a different username. Otherwise, it's not correctly installed I guess.

Comment: No, it was other issue.. ".gradle" system folder was hidden.. So I go to Go=>Go To Folder and than I found .gradle folder.. Thanks for the fast reply..

Answer (score 14):

You could make the process faster, if you use gradle from command line. There is a lot of optimization to do for the IDE developers. But it is just an early version.

For more information read [this discussion](https://plus.google.com/u/0/110774282522099816721/posts/e9PG6vSN5w3) on g+ with some of the devs.

Comment: This seems to be true even now in 2016

Answer (score 11):

If anyone is working a project which is synced via Subversion and this still happening, I think this can slow the process of workflow in Android Studio. For example if it work very slow while: scrolling in a class,xml etc, while my app is still running on my device.

- Go to Version Control at Preferences, and set from Subversion to None.[image]

Comment: You save my day: 2/4 min -> 15sec (I disabled Tortoise HG for project).

Comment: If anyone is still using Subversion, they should switch to Git or Mercurial

Answer (score 8):

## **Update After Android Studio 2.3**

All answers are great, and I encourage to use those methods with this one to improve build speed.

After release of android 2.2 on September 2016, Android released *experimental* build cache feature to speed up `gradle` build performance, which is now official from Android Studio 2.3 Canary. [(Official Release note)](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/build-cache)

It introduces a new build cache feature, which is enable by default, can speed up build times (including full builds, incremental builds, and instant run) by storing and reusing files/directories that were created in previous builds of the same or different Android project.

**How to use:**

Add following line in your `gradle.properties` file

```
android.enableBuildCache = true
# Set to true or false to enable or disable the build cache. If this parameter is not set, the build cache is enable by default.
```

**Clean the cache:**

- There is a new Gradle task called `cleanBuildCache` for you to more easily clean the build cache. You can use it by typing the following in your terminal:

  `./gradlew cleanBuildCache`
- OR You can clean the cache for Android studio 2.2 by deleting all the files store at location

  `C:\Users\<username>\.android\build-cache`

Answer (score 7):

After change this settings my compile duration 10 minutes changed to ~10 secs.

**Step 1:**

> Settings(ctrl+Alt+S) ->
>
> Build,Execution,Deployment ->
>
> Compiler ->
>
> type "`--offline`" in command-line Options box.

**Step 2:**

> check the “Compile independent modules in parallel” checkbox.
>
> & click Apply -> OK

[image]

Reference - https://www.sundoginteractive.com/blog/speed-up-gradle-in-android-studio

**Disadvantage:**

You will not be able to pull down the latest versions of the dependencies identified in your build.gradle file. It runs faster because it uses a cached snapshot of those imported libraries.

**Important Note**: When you deploy the application remove this settings & build with latest versions of dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

Solved mine with

> `File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools ->`
>   `Gradle -> Offline work`

Gradle builds went from 8 minutes to 3 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what helped this beginning Android programmer (former professional programmer, years ago) in speeding up Android Studio 2.2. I know this is a rehash, but, just **summarizing** in one place.

Initial builds can still be brutally slow, but restarts of running apps are now usually very tolerable. I'm using a sub-optimal PC: AMD Quad-Core A8-7410 CPU, 8MB RAM, non-SSD HD, Win 10. (And, this is my first Stack Overflow posting.... ;)

**IN SETTINGS -> GRADLE:**

yes for "Offline work"  (this is perhaps the most import setting).

**IN SETTINGS -> COMPILER:**

yes for "Compile independent modules in parallel"  (not sure if this does in fact help utilize multicore CPUs).

**IN GRADLE SCRIPTS**, "build.gradle (Module: app)":

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
   // keep min high so that restarted apps can be hotswapped...obviously, this is hugely faster.
   minSdkVersion 14
   ...
    // enabling multidex support...does make big difference for me.
    multiDexEnabled true
```

**ALSO IN GRADLE SCRIPTS**, "gradle.properties (Project Properties)":

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx3048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.daemon=true

**Additionally**, testing on a physical device instead of the emulator is working well for me; a small tablet that stands up is convenient.

Answer (score 4):

Just another performance imporvement tip:

**Android Studio 3.0** includes new DEX compiler called D8.

"The dex compiler mostly works under the hood in your day-to-day app development, but it directly impacts your app's build time, .dex file size, and runtime performance."

"And when comparing the new D8 compiler with the current DX compiler, D8 compiles faster and outputs smaller .dex files, while having the same or better app runtime performance."

D8 is optional - do use it we have to put to project's gradle.properties

```
android.enableD8=true
```

More informations: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/next-generation-dex-compiler-now-in.html

PS. It impove my build time by about 30%.

Answer (score 1):

This setup goes really fast for me 
(about 2 seconds the build)

**build.gradle**

```
android {

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        preDexLibraries = false
        jumboMode = false
        maxProcessCount 4
        javaMaxHeapSize "6g"
    }
}
```

**gradle.properties**

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx8192M
```

**my PC:**

- CPU  Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU G2030 @ 3.00GHz, 3000 Mhz, 2 procesadores
  principales, 2 procesadores lógicos
- x64
- Microsoft Windows 7 Professional
- (RAM) 16,0 GB

**project files**
 - All located in local HD

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the following steps.

1. Enable offline mode :  Please check below print screen.

   https://i.stack.imgur.com/RF9uG.png
2. Enable Instant Run : Please check below print screen.

   https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvHKJ.png

   If you want to learn more about instant run please visit android developer site.

Answer (score 1):

You could try opening the gradle menu on the right side of studio, and assemble only the modules you have changed, then run the install command. When you press run it assembles everything regardless of any changes you you may have made to the code it is assembling

Answer (score 0):

I'm far from being an expert on Gradle but my environment had the following line in .gradle/init.gradle

```
gradle.projectsLoaded {
    rootProject.allprojects {
        repositories {
            mavenRepo name: 'libs-repo', url: 'http://guest-vm/artifactory/repo'
        }
    }
}
```

Yet I have no idea why that line was there, but I try changing to

```
gradle.projectsLoaded {
    rootProject.allprojects {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
}
```

and now I finally can work without swearing to Android Studio & Gradle buildind scheme.

Comment: artifactory in your case was probably used as a library cache. You contact the artifactory server which look if it have the library. If yes it return it to you otherwise it goes and fetch it from mavencentral and then return to you.

Answer (score 0):

In our specific case, the problem was due to having the **retrolambda** plugin, which forced all projects and subprojects to recompile everytime we tried to launch our application, even if no code had been altered in our core modules.

Removing **retrolamba** fixed it for us. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this first. It is my personal experience.

I had the same problem. What i had done is just permanently disable the antivirus (Mine was Avast Security 2015). Just after  disabling the antivirus , thing gone well.   the gradle  finished successfully. 
From now within seconds the gradle is finishing ( Only taking 5-10 secs).

Answer (score 0):

Hi I know this is very very late answer but maybe help someone
in my case I was using

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
```

in my app Gradle dependency
but in one of my libraries it was

```
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
```

after change all to latest version my problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Following the steps will make it 10 times faster and reduce build time 90%

First create a file named gradle.properties in the following directory:

```
/home/<username>/.gradle/ (Linux)
/Users/<username>/.gradle/ (Mac)
C:\Users\<username>\.gradle (Windows)
```

Add this line to the file:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

And check this options in Android Studio

[image]

Answer (score 0):

USE this
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386

[Android Studio fails to build new project, timed out while wating for slave aapt process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30111443/android-studio-fails-to-build-new-project-timed-out-while-wating-for-slave-aapt/31095817#31095817)

Answer (score 0):

A **trivial** change (to a resoruce xml) still took **10 minutes**.
As **@rivare** says in his answer, a command line build is mutch faster (took this down to **15** **seconds**).
Here are some steps to at least make a trivial build fast from the command line for Windows.

1. **Go** to your projects root (where the gradlew.bat is):

   cd c:\android\MaskActivity
2. execute the **build**:

   gradlew assembleDebug
3. **uninstall** the apk from the phone directly (drag it to uninstall).
4. When the build is finished, **kill** the BIG java process using Windows
   Task Manager.

OR if you have unix tools on your Windows machine:

```
ps
```

"pid" 's are shown:

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

5. Now **install** your apk:

   adb -d install C:\Android\MaskActivity\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk

Answer (score 0):

According to the [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build.html#dex_options), add this in the gradle file of app module.

```
android {
    ...
    dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries true
    maxProcessCount 8
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**To run Android envirorment on low configuration machine.**

1. Close the uncessesory web tabs in browser
2. For Antivirus users, exclude the build folder which is auto generated
3. Android studio have 1.2 Gb default heap can decrease to 512 MB
   Help > Edit custom VM options
   studio.vmoptions
   -Xmx512m
   Layouts performace will be speed up
4. For Gradle one of the core component in Android studio Mkae sure
   like right now 3.0beta is latest one

**Below tips can affect the code quality so please use with cautions:**

1. Studio contain Power safe Mode when turned on it will close background operations that lint , code complelitions and so on.
2. You can run manually lintcheck when needed ./gradlew lint
3. Most of are using Android emulators on average it consume 2 GB RAM so if possible use actual Android device these will reduce your resource load on your computer. Alternatively you can reduce the RAM of the emulator and it will automatically reduce the virtual memory consumption on your computer. you can find this in virtual device configuration and advance setting.
4. Gradle offline mode is a feature for bandwidth limited users to disable the downloading of build dependencies. It will reduce the background operation that will help to increase the performance of Android studio.
5. Android studio offers an optimization to compile multiple modules in parallel. On low RAM machines this feature will likely have a negative impact on the performance. You can disable it in the compiler settings dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I was fed up with the slow build of android on my local machine. The way I solved this was spinning up a high-end machine on AWS and rsyncing the code from my local to the machine and compiling it over there.

I saw an immediate increase in the performance and my local system was saved from CPU hog. Check out this tool I created to help the developers speed up their terminal https://stormyapp.com