# Every run of projects in android studio is slow

Tags: ide, android-studio

Because I think it always makes/build/etc every time I run the project, unlike in eclipse when I run the project it immediately installed in the device. Is there any workaround here to run the project like in eclipse?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Building and running app via Gradle and Android Studio is slower than via Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775197/building-and-running-app-via-gradle-and-android-studio-is-slower-than-via-eclips)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, that would answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio is slower than eclipse in many ways. I don't think there is a way of speeding the software up all together from the user side, all we can do it wait for a update for the software.

Follow this post: [Android studio Gradle build speed up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324849/android-studio-gradle-build-speed-up?newreg=a334a7da9a344f7ca4e670704250ab42)

Might help you make things faster on Android Studio.

Comment: It seems slow in every way possible.