# Android Studio Google JAR file causing GC overhead limit exceeded error

Tags: java, android, overhead

I am using Android Studio on OS X. I am getting this error message:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
>     com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4W/dx --dex --output /Users/alex/AndroidStudioProjects/SilentSMS/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/android-4.3_r2.1-f22bbff4d1017230e169a4844a9c2195f13060d2.jar /Users/alex/AndroidStudioProjects/SilentSMS/app/libs/android-4.3_r2.1.jar
>
>   Error Code:
>     3
>     Output:

```
  UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
      at com.android.dx.cf.code.RopperMachine.getSources(RopperMachine.java:665)
      at com.android.dx.cf.code.RopperMachine.run(RopperMachine.java:288)
      at com.android.dx.cf.code.Simulator$SimVisitor.visitLocal(Simulator.java:612)
      at com.android.dx.cf.code.BytecodeArray.parseInstruction(BytecodeArray.java:412)
      at com.android.dx.cf.code.Simulator.simulate(Simulator.java:94)
      at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.processBlock(Ropper.java:782)
      at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.doit(Ropper.java:737)
      at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.convert(Ropper.java:346)
      at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:282)
      at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:139)
      at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:94)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:682)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
      at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
      at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
      at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
      at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

I am using this library:

http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/

I pulled the JAR file and added it to my project - the project I am trying to build is:

https://github.com/domi007/silentSMS/

I understand it is because my xms and xmx values are too low. I increased them in:

/Applications/Android Studio.app/bin/idea.vmoptions so that it now says:

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

However, I still get the error. What could this be caused by? Apart from the silentSMS app being an Eclipse project and me porting the code over to Android Studio I haven't changed anything. In terms of Android Studio spotting errors - it doesn't, and everything else looks fine.

Answer (score 551, accepted):

I think there's a separate way to raise the heap limit of the dexing operation. Add this to your `android` closure in your `build.gradle` file:

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

and see if that helps.

(idea courtesy of [this answer from Scott Barta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25006075/extremely-long-build-with-gradle-android-studio/25006428#25006428))

Comment: `4g` is a bit overkill, `2g` is ok

Comment: Fantastic! This also fixed my error. I find that the more memory I give it, the fast the build goes. I went from over 1 min to 19 sec.

Comment: After enabling multidex build duration rased from 2 mins up to 6-7 mins. Now it takes the same 2 minutes again!

Comment: I am getting this error even after adding this option in Android Studio 2.1 Beta 2

Comment: Same thing here, something wrong with Android Studio 2.1 Beta 2

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the latest version of AS (2.1 Beta 2), this might be the cause.

Comment: 2g is enough than 4g

Comment: I still get the error:  **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
[org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.AntLoggingAdapter] at java.util.BitSet.clone**

Comment: I have added this, but I still see `OutOfMemoryError`

Comment: This is working, thank's ! But is their any backwards of increasing java max heap size?

Comment: @Simon You said: "I find that the more memory I give it, the fast the build goes." I gave it javaMaxHeapSize "4g" and I also noticed that my build was much faster than usual! What are the trade-offs of giving an excessive amount of memory though?

Comment: Well I guess u have less memory for the rest of your running tasks on your computer during build time but for me, that was not an issue.

Comment: didn't work for me, needed to up in gradle.properties:
`org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xms1024m -Xmx4096m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=1024m`

Comment: I put it on 16GB still doesn't owrk

Comment: In Arctic Fox this produces a warning: "DSL element 'dexOptions' is obsolete and should be removed. It will be removed in version 8.0 of the Android Gradle plugin. Using it has no effect, and the AndroidGradle plugin optimizes dexing automatically."

Answer (score 95):

In my case, to increase the **heap-size** looks like this:

Using Android Studio 1.1.0

```
android {
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
    }
}
```

Put the above code in your ***Build.gradle*** file.

Comment: this worked to overcome `GC overhead limit exceeded` after I enabled Multidexing. The exception was in `at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:334)`

Comment: this isn't going to be pretty as a comment, but the Android Studio error showed `   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` The location of exception was at `at com.android.dx.util.FixedSizeList.<init>(FixedSizeList.java:38)` and top of stack was `com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:244)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)`

Comment: But as soon as I added you suggested javaMaxHeapSize and incremental parameters, Android Studio was able to build the multi-dexed app.

Comment: if 2gb isn't enough a some point, then I'll try 4gb that commonware suggested.

Comment: Thanks. Notice what the docs say about `incremental`: *This has many limitations and may not work. Use carefully.*

Comment: incremental is not tagged as deprecated

Answer (score 46):

This new issue is caused by the latest version of Android.

Go to your project root folder, open `gradle.properties`, and add the following options:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

org.gradle.parallel=true

org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

Then add these changes in your `build.gradle` file:

```
dexOptions {
        incremental = true
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" // 2g should be also OK
}
```

Comment: Warning:The `android.dexOptions.incremental` property is deprecated and it has no effect on the build process.

Comment: this solved my issue. but i;ts creating a file called java_pid1512.hprof which is very large. i am guessing your Dfile option is creating it ? is it necessary and can you show how to remove the dump to file

Comment: @j2emanue: This file is created because of the "HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError" option: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15062/optionxx.htm#BABDJEJI

Comment: May need to updated: `incremental` is deleted in the end of 2018

Comment: in AS 3.4 enabling the "org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" in the gradle.properties file solved the issue for me

Answer (score 10):

Android Studio 3.5.3

Find the Memory Settings (Cmd + Shift + A on Mac or click on Help and start typing "Memory Settings") under Preferences/ Settings and increase the IDE Heap Size and/ or the Daemon Heap Size to your satisfaction
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I disable my Instant Run by:

Menu *Preference* → *Build* → *Instant Run "Enable Instant Run to hot swap code"*

I guess it is the Instant Run that makes the build slow and creates a large size pidXXX.hprof file which causes the AndroidStudio gc overhead limit exceeded.

(My device SDK is 19.)

Comment: How did you find out it was Instant Run that created such a large hprof file? I noticed one created recently on our GitLab server, but we don't have instant run enabled.

Answer (score 1):

For me non of the answers worked I saw here worked. I guessed that having the CPU work extremely hard makes the computer hot. After I closed programs that consume large amounts of CPU (like chrome) and cooling down my laptop the problem disappeared.

For reference: I had the CPU on 96%-97% and Memory usage over 2,000,000K by a java.exe process (which was actually gradle related process).

Comment: How does your solution relate to the SPECIFIC problem posed here?

Comment: I get the same error specified above:
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
The solution I offered solved this error for me

Answer (score 1):

Add this to build.gradle file

```
dexOptions {
   javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

4g is a bit overkill, if you do not want to change buildGradle you can use FILE -> Invalid caches / restart.

Thats work fine for me ...

Answer (score 0):

I forced closed all Java.exe from taskmanger, restarted Android Studio and it worked for me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `Android Studio 3.4` and **the only thing that worked for me** was to remove the following lines from my `build.gradle` file:

```
minifyEnabled true
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

Because `Android Studio 3.4` is using `R8` in `full mode` and is not direct compatible with `Proguard`

Comment: I think this isn't a solution when you have to release an obfuscated build. I have used **gradle-5.2.1** with **Android Studio 3.4** and it's working fine even with the `minifyEnabled true` with pro-guard configuration while **gradle-5.1.1** was having similar issues.

Comment: This is the exact opposite of what we want. -1

Comment: Like I said, this worked for me and the error is gone and finally I was able to generate the apk. None of the others answers worked in my project.

Comment: update gradle to **5.2.1** run cammand in   **/project/android** 
 `./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=5.2.1`

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I Edit my  `gradle.properties` :

note: if u enable the  `minifyEnabled true` :

remove this line :

```
android.enableR8=true
```

and add this lines in ur `build.gradle` , `android` block :

```
  dexOptions {
        incremental = true
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" // 2g should be also OK
    }
```

hope this help some one :)

Answer (score 0):

At some point a duplicate copy of `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` got added to my build gradle. Removing the duplicate copy and making sure all my apply plugins were at the  top fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions mentioned above, but I was still facing the issue.
Finally I stumbled upon the following which resolved the issue.

(On MacOS) Went to Preferences -> Memory Settings -> Find existing grade demon(s) -> Stopped all of them.