# Can't add both Google Play Services and Appcompat-v7 dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services, android-appcompat

I am trying to clean up and update the libraries on a project. As part of this I moved from using the classic library folder dependency to one through gradle, for Google Play Services. I started getting an dexDebug error when compiling debug (see  [Android Studio - UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102598/android-studio-unexpected-top-level-exception) ). From what I understand this error shows up if you have a double dependency somehow.

Below is the dependencies part of my gradle file. If I comment out appcompat-v7 completely, everything works fine. Does play-services already depend on appcompatv7 and automatically bringing it in or what's going on?

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3'

//compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.8-sources.jar')
compile files('libs/engine.io-client-0.2.3.jar')
compile files('libs/ffmpeg.jar')
compile files('libs/Java-WebSocket-1.3.0.jar')
compile files('libs/socket.io-client-0.1.3.jar')
//compile files('libs/javacpp.jar')
compile files('libs/javacv.jar')
compile files('libs/json-simple-1.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/opencv.jar')
//compile files('libs/twitter4j-async-4.0.2.jar')
compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.2.jar')
//compile files('libs/twitter4j-media-support-4.0.2.jar')
//compile files('libs/twitter4j-stream-4.0.2.jar')
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out there was an exact duplicate to this question:

[After update of AS to 1.0, getting "method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536" error in project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27377080/after-update-of-as-to-1-0-getting-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536-error-i)

I fixed it by adding (this alone will fix the original problem):

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

and by cutting down on the massive Google Play Services, and using only subsets of it (this alone will also fix the original problem):

```
dependencies {
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'

compile files('libs/engine.io-client-0.2.3.jar')
compile files('libs/ffmpeg.jar')
compile files('libs/Java-WebSocket-1.3.0.jar')
compile files('libs/socket.io-client-0.1.3.jar')
compile files('libs/javacv.jar')
compile files('libs/json-simple-1.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/opencv.jar')
compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.2.jar')
```

}

Comment: Slow down. You do not want multidex. Covert from libs to Gradle depdenencies(the whole point of Gradle and Maven).

Comment: Well I did do that for the big ones, Google Play Services and appcompat-v7 and then I ran into the issue. I'm updating my answer with what else I did (cut down on Google Play Services)