# How to build the native Android sources from Codename One's build server

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, codenameone, android-studio-import

I'm using the new [gradle build switch](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/material-icons-background-music-geofencing-gradle.html) when sending an Android build for Codename One. One of the highlighted benefits of building with gradle is the ability to open/run in Android Studio and indeed the project opens for me but I'm getting the following error:

> Error:Unable to load class
>   'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StringGroovyMethods'. Possible causes for
>   this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's dependency cache may be
>     corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.) Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires
>     network)
> - The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may
>     be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem. Stop Gradle build processes (requires
>     restart)
> - Your project may be using a third-party plugin
>     which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the
>     version of Gradle requested by the project.
>
> In the case of
>   corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then
>   killing all Java processes.

I restarted the process, the IDE and did quite a few things with no real success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same issue and corresponded with Codename One support a while back and it turns out the solution is rather simple:

Define your own installation of gradle as the one to use, this is what Chen from CodenameOne sent to me as a reference:

[image: screenshot from Chen]

I installed gradle 2.8 and configured it as such in the settings and that almost worked. I also had to follow the instructions of [Android Studio - supplied javaHome is not a valid folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22749200/android-studio-supplied-javahome-is-not-a-valid-folder) & even [After update of AS to 1.0, getting "method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536" error in project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27377080/after-update-of-as-to-1-0-getting-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536-error-i) despite the fact that multi-sex was not necessary in the server?