# Which SDK and Build Tools versions do I use to compile sources generated from the CN1 build server?

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to debug code as it runs on my Android test device.  I sent a build to the CN1 server and downloaded the resulting sources.zip, which I then used to create a project in Android Developer Studio.

When I compile using
Compile SDK Version: API21 or API 22 with
Build Tools Version: 21.1.2 or 22.0.1, respectively

I get the following compile errors:

```
C:\home\dev\ProxyServerDebug\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v23\values-v23.xml
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(18) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\opt\android-sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

When I compile using
Compile SDK Version: API 23
Build Tools Version: 23.0.2

I get the following compile errors:

```
C:\home\dev\ProxyServerDebug\src\main\java\com\codename1\impl\android\AndroidImplementation.java
Error:(4563, 21) error: cannot find symbol method setLatestEventInfo(Activity,String,String,PendingIntent)
C:\home\dev\ProxyServerDebug\src\main\java\com\codename1\impl\android\PushNotificationService.java
Error:(110, 18) error: cannot find symbol method setLatestEventInfo(PushNotificationService,String,String,PendingIntent)
```

Is it just a matter of setting the correct SDK and Build Tools versions?  or am I missing something else?  BTW, sources were generated this morning, so I should be on the latest CN1 3.3 release.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly it should be `22.0.1` the reason build fails by default is that you need to configure an external gradle directory as explained in [How to build the native Android sources from Codename One's build server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34430404/how-to-build-the-native-android-sources-from-codename-ones-build-server/34431311#34431311)

Comment: Thanks, Shai.  Your answer lead me to a solution.  As explained in the URL you referenced above, I needed to make a few changes to Android Studio Gradle Settings.  The settings had already contained a Gradle Home set to the gradle 2.8 directory within my Android Studio.  I downloaded the latest grade version 2.10, and pointed to the new installation directory which was outside of the studio.  I got some further errors.  I then decided to download gradle 2.2 and pointed the home at that, and that worked.