# How to avoid android.support.v4.content.Loader.OnLoadCompleteListener has already been added on android studio

Tags: java, android, memory, android-studio

I had a problem with on Android studio, I tried a lot of tucks but no results:

and this my error :

```
Error:Class android.support.v4.content.Loader.OnLoadCompleteListener has already been added to output. Please remove duplicate copies.
```

so this is my gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
          }
}

android {

      dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
          javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

   /* signingConfigs {
        debug_config {
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
           storeFile file('C:\\Users\\Euphor\\.android\\debug.keystore')  //Windows path
          //  storeFile file('/Users/Euphor/.android/debug.keystore')  //Mac path
            storePassword 'android'
        }
        release_config {

*//*            keyAlias 'uness_droid'
            keyPassword 'paperpadeuphor2014'
            //storeFile file('C:/Users/euphordev02/Desktop/devs/keystoreAppServices')  //Windows path
            storeFile file('/Users/Euphor/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/Generated Projects Data/paperpadkeystore')  //Mac path
            storePassword 'paperpadeuphor2014'*//*

            keyAlias 'euphor-paperpad'
            keyPassword 'paperpadeuphor2013'
            storeFile file('C:\\Users\\Euphor\\AndroidStudioProjects\\Generated Projects Data')  //Windows path
          //  storeFile file('/Users/Euphor/Desktop/AndroidStudioProjects/Generated Projects Data/keystoreAppServices')  //Mac path
            storePassword 'paperpadeuphor2013'
        }
    }*/
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.euphor.paperpad"
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
                  }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {

            debuggable true
           // signingConfig signingConfigs.debug_config
            renderscriptDebuggable false
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        Business {
            applicationId "com.euphor.paperpad"
            manifestPlaceholders = [activityLabel : "Business", gcmPackage : "com.euphor.paperpad"]
            minSdkVersion 11
          //  signingConfig signingConfigs.debug_config
            targetSdkVersion 21
            versionCode 129
            versionName '0.8.2'
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
            //set("crashlyticsApiKey", "023e7fe8a4a93f93ffe7510201929d081b125313")
            //set("crashlyticsApiSecret", "fe4680d06d3dce0537bab77fc97ff48bb7803a6091c916ac0c285e50d9dd0fa5")
        }
        BusinessApps {
            applicationId "com.paperpad.GrandMonarque"
            minSdkVersion 11
        //    signingConfig signingConfigs.debug_config
            targetSdkVersion 21
            versionCode 129
            versionName '0.8.2'
          /*  ext.enableCrashlytics = true
            set("crashlyticsApiKey", "023e7fe8a4a93f93ffe7510201929d081b125313")
            set("crashlyticsApiSecret", "fe4680d06d3dce0537bab77fc97ff48bb7803a6091c916ac0c285e50d9dd0fa5")*/
        }

        BusinessApp1 {
            applicationId "com.paperpad.HotelMinistere"
            minSdkVersion 11
        //    signingConfig signingConfigs.debug_config
            targetSdkVersion 21
            versionCode 128
            versionName '0.8.1'
           //ext.enableCrashlytics = true
            //set("crashlyticsApiKey", "023e7fe8a4a93f93ffe7510201929d081b125313")
          //  set("crashlyticsApiSecret", "fe4680d06d3dce0537bab77fc97ff48bb7803a6091c916ac0c285e50d9dd0fa5")
        }

        BusinessApp2 {
            applicationId "com.paperpad.DomainePresVerts"
            minSdkVersion 11
//            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug_config
            targetSdkVersion 21
            versionCode 129
            versionName '0.8.2'
           // ext.enableCrashlytics = true
          //  set("crashlyticsApiKey", "023e7fe8a4a93f93ffe7510201929d081b125313")
          //  set("crashlyticsApiSecret", "fe4680d06d3dce0537bab77fc97ff48bb7803a6091c916ac0c285e50d9dd0fa5")
        }

        BusinessApp3 {
            applicationId "com.paperpad.LeLana"
            minSdkVersion 11
     //       signingConfig signingConfigs.debug_config
            targetSdkVersion 21
            versionCode 128
            versionName '0.8.1'
            //ext.enableCrashlytics = true
            //set("crashlyticsApiKey", "023e7fe8a4a93f93ffe7510201929d081b125313")
            //set("crashlyticsApiSecret", "fe4680d06d3dce0537bab77fc97ff48bb7803a6091c916ac0c285e50d9dd0fa5")
        }

        BusinessApp4 {
            applicationId "com.paperpad.GrandHotelContinental"
            minSdkVersion 11
      //      signingConfig signingConfigs.debug_config
            targetSdkVersion 21
            versionCode 128
            versionName '0.8.1'
           // ext.enableCrashlytics = true
           // set("crashlyticsApiKey", "023e7fe8a4a93f93ffe7510201929d081b125313")
           // set("crashlyticsApiSecret", "fe4680d06d3dce0537bab77fc97ff48bb7803a6091c916ac0c285e50d9dd0fa5")
        }
    }
    sourceSets {

        Business {
            manifest.srcFile 'Business/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }

        BusinessApps {
            manifest.srcFile 'BusinessApps/AndroidManifest.xml'
            assets.srcDirs = ['BusinessApps/assets']
        }

        BusinessApp1 {
            manifest.srcFile 'BusinessApp1/AndroidManifest.xml'
            assets.srcDirs = ['BusinessApp1/assets']

        }

        BusinessApp2 {
            manifest.srcFile 'BusinessApp2/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }

        BusinessApp3 {
            manifest.srcFile 'BusinessApp3/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }

        BusinessApp4 {
         //   manifest.srcFile 'BusinessApp4/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }


}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}

dependencies {

    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0')
    compile ('com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.4')
    compile files('libs/json-simple-1.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/ormlite-android-4.45.jar')
    compile files('libs/ormlite-core-4.45.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-databind-2.1.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.1.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-annotations-2.1.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile files('libs/paralloidviews.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsr250-api-1.0.jar')
    compile project(':volley')
    compile project(':Android-RSS-Reader-Library-master')
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile project(':Forecast')
    compile project(':headerListView')
    compile project(':library-sliding-menu')
    compile files('libs/panoramagl.jar')
    compile project(':paymentKit_lib')
    compile project(':ProgressWheel-master')
    compile project(':stripe')
    compile project(':UIL_library')
    compile files('libs/coverflowlibrary.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')

   // compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')

}
```

please guys help me I struggle with this problem, I f u wanna more information I'm here

Comment: i never had java.lang.OutOFmemory exception using android studio

Comment: it's my third day and I struggle with this error, can you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Please add this to your `build.gradle`:

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25013822/503508

Comment: it gives me another error, also I tried to resolve it but I don't know where are the diplucate items, can you help me please !

Comment: IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompatIceCreamSandwich seems like you have two copies of the support library added. See if you have added it twice somewhere.

Comment: it's 3 hours of searching and I didn't found it, can you please help me ?

Comment: It might be that you have both the support jar and dependency in your dendency list. `compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')` and `compile('com.android.support:support-v4:21.+')`. You should remove the .jar dependency.

Comment: even I tried it, I had the same error right now any other suggestion and thank's .?