# another app:dexDebug error Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have a working project and Now I want to implement a new library which name is seamless ad network api.
While I add the api in dependencies and build it with no problems, I try to debug the app and then it gives the error below.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. >com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal. 
ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3
```

I tried all different solutions mentioned in similar stackoverflow questions but no luck! 
I have tried adding multidexEnabled true but didnt work
I have tried adding compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0' but didnt work
I have tried to comment out other jar files that mentioned in dependencies but didnt work. what is wrong with this?

here is my build.gradle in app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android 
{
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION
    targetSdkVersion ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

repositories {
maven {
    url "http://maven.seamlessapi.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/"
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
//compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.0.jar')
compile project(':Libraries:CropImageLib')
compile project(':Libraries:facebook-android')
compile project(':Libraries:NineOldLibs')
compile project(':Libraries:SlidingMenu')
compile files('libs/JTransforms-3.0.jar')
compile files('libs/JLargeArrays-1.2.jar')
compile files('libs/gdata-core-1.0.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
compile 'com.goseamless:seamless:2.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

here is the full error log

```
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex UP-TO-DATE
:app:shrinkDebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
:app:createDebugMainDexClassList UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.BitSet.initWords(BitSet.java:166)
at java.util.BitSet.<init>(BitSet.java:161)
at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaMethod.bitSetFromLabelList(SsaMethod.java:137)
at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaBasicBlock.newFromRop(SsaBasicBlock.java:161)
at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaMethod.convertRopToSsaBlocks(SsaMethod.java:173)
at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaMethod.newFromRopMethod(SsaMethod.java:103)
at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaConverter.convertToSsaMethod(SsaConverter.java:44)
at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:98)
at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:72)
at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:297)
at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:137)
at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:93)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:729)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
at     com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:505)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:334)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:244)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:    org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3
```

Comment: Please show full error log.

Comment: I have posted, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I have found the answer. when Anand Singh asked for full error log, I have got the clue. 
     java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space 
then I have found this solution.
adding

```
dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
    }
```

thanks to Dhruv 
[Android Studio Google JAR file causing GC overhead limit exceeded error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25013638/android-studio-google-jar-causing-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-error/29212126#29212126)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your libraries are duplicating in **dependencies** and in **libs** folder. If you add some .jar file in a libs folder - don't paste its `compile 'com.android...'` version in build.app.