# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded on Android 1.4

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

I get an **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded** when run gradle on Android 1.4 ...
these are my depedencies :

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':android-crop')
    compile project(':RTEditor-Toolbar')

        compile files('libs/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar')
        compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.3.jar')
    /*    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.1.jar')*/
    compile files('libs/jetbrains-annotations.jar')
    compile files('libs/pinchzoom.jar')
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    //three party library
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
    compile 'com.vinaysshenoy:mugen:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.5.5'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.curioustechizen.android-ago:library:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.4.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: add  `dexOptions {
        // Prevent OutOfMemory with MultiDex during the build phase
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }` in your **build.gradle**

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Add this to your android closure(build gradle):

```
 dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
 }
```

This will solve your problem. Still, if you face problem see the following link

[GC overhead limit exceeded error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25013638/android-studio-google-jar-causing-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-error)

Comment: `incremental true` is deprecated now, and have no effect on build process.
So, can be ignored.

Comment: didn't help, I set it to 12gigs and still got the error

Comment: @ÁbrahámEndre can you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643102/android-studio-2-1-instant-run-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exc

Comment: already tried that, I've started the IDE with -Xmx4096 and even turned out the GCOverhead, did the same for gradle.properties too and still ran out. Problem is not present if I remove facebook SDK.

Comment: just for clarification, add it to `app/build.gradle` inside the `android { }` object.

Answer (score 51):

This is what I suggest:

Add this to your "gradle.properties" file:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

Also, read [**this article**](https://medium.com/@cesarmcferreira/speeding-up-gradle-builds-619c442113cb#.ivx4r9q9d). You might be able to make the building a bit faster, by adding a combination of those:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

Comment: Aren't those incubating features?

Comment: daemon is ON by default in the latest gradle versions.

Answer (score 9):

In my case, OutOfMemoryError is come from this error. [Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy and 6 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49074620/7891350)

To solve this. I use `./gradlew --stop` or `./gradle --stop`.
If still not solved which mean the gradle process is lock (this happen after OutOfMemoryError).

Go to `/users/[username]/.gradle/daemon` (hidden) folder.

You will see each built gradle version folder like `3.2  3.3  4.0.1  4.1  4.10.1  4.10.2  4.4  4.6  5.4.1  5.5`

Go into these folders and remove the file named

> registry.bin
>
> registry.bin.lock

For me, I remove all these folders.

Then rebuild you app. Should be work now.

Comment: This is it. This is the answer. Works like a charm

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me !!
Just add the following lines into "gradle.properties" file

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

Comment: This answer was given by @android-developer three years previously and with more detail - don't copy other people's answers please.

Answer (score 3):

When JVM/Dalvik spends more than 98% doing GC and only 2% or less of the heap size is recovered the “**java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded**” is thrown.

The solution is to extend heap space or use profiling tools/memory dump analyzers and try to find the cause of the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by **extend heap space**?

Answer (score 2):

My test were failing in gradle version 5.2.1 **"GC overhead limit exceeded java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded"**. I solved by adding **maxHeapSize** in  build.gradle like below:

```
 test {
        maxHeapSize = "4g"
    }
```

Comment: I had this issue using when running a test that loaded an Excel file with Apache POI. Setting the `maxHeapSize` to 1g in the `test` section of my `build.gradle` file resolved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

just go to prefrence or settings -> memori settings -> and setup your alocated memory

android studio 3.5