# How can i solve error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded?

Tags: android, runtime-error

I update my *Android Studio* and try to run an app but it shows the error like this..

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

before updation of *Android Studio* same app run fine, so i tried to solve the issue i found only one which is i already done into *gradle* file..

```
dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

So now what can i do to solve this issue, please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: android:largeHeap="true" in AndroidManifest.xml in application tag and clear cache !

Comment: That's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. go to "System Properties"  -> "Advanced"
2. Environment Variables
3. Edit _JAVA_OPTIONS values from  "-Xms1024m" to "-Xms2048m"
   (if not Exist _JAVA_OPTIONS  then create it by clicking on New Button)
4. Ok, save and restart system

I think it will be helpfull for you

Comment: your system have not enough memory free some memory   this solution worked for me

Comment: remove any virtual device or try to clear caches. delete .gradle folder or you can search another question for opening the android studio.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your `gradle.properties` file.

```
# The Gradle daemon aims to improve the startup and execution time of Gradle.
# When set to true the Gradle daemon is to run the build.
org.gradle.daemon=true

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
org.gradle.parallel=true

# Enables new incubating mode that makes Gradle selective when configuring projects.
# Only relevant projects are configured which results in faster builds for large multi-projects.
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:configuration_on_demand
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

And on my `build.gradle` :

```
....
     dexOptions
         {
               incremental false
               javaMaxHeapSize "2048M" 
               preDexLibraries = false
         }//end dexOptions

....
```

Found [Here](https://medium.com/@cesarmcferreira/speeding-up-gradle-builds-619c442113cb#.81pvdbodq)

And My answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36644752/3626214)