# Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy and 6 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

Tags: gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When I was running the `gradle clean` command, I got the following message

> Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy and 6 stopped Daemons could not be
>   reused, use --status for details

For the investigation, I run the following command.

```
$ gradle --status
   PID STATUS   INFO
 11506 BUSY     4.3.1
  8027 STOPPED  (stop command received)
  9347 STOPPED  (stop command received)
 11727 STOPPED  (by user or operating system)
  4786 STOPPED  (by user or operating system)
 14569 STOPPED  (by user or operating system)
 31237 STOPPED  (by user or operating system)

Only Daemons for the current Gradle version are displayed. See https://docs.gradle.org/4.3.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:status
```

So, some questions have arisen in my mind.

1. **How can I stop an existing daemon?**
2. **How to kill daemon process?**

Answer (score 59, accepted):

> **Stopping an existing Daemon:**

If you want to explicitly stop running Daemon processes for any reason, just use the command `gradle --stop`.

**Note:** for your consideration the `gradle --stop` command won’t stop daemons running with a different version of Gradle.

> **How to kill all Daemon process on my machine?**

Gradle will kill any Daemon that has been idle for 3 hours or more, so you don’t have to worry about cleaning them up manually.

**Resource Link:** [Gradle Daemon Issue Details](https://docs.gradle.org/4.3.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:status)

So the command and output are given below:

```
$ gradle --stop
Stopping Daemon(s)
2 Daemons stopped
```

After stopping daemons, status will be look like below:

```
$ gradle --status
No Gradle daemons are running.
   PID STATUS   INFO
  8027 STOPPED  (stop command received)
  9347 STOPPED  (stop command received)
 12448 STOPPED  (stop command received)
 11506 STOPPED  (stop command received)
 11727 STOPPED  (by user or operating system)
  4786 STOPPED  (by user or operating system)
 14569 STOPPED  (by user or operating system)
 31237 STOPPED  (by user or operating system)
```

If you are **stuck with gradle build running**, you can to through this post: **[Stuck with Gradle Build Running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063217/stuck-with-gradle-build-running)**

Comment: You haven't answered the implied question, which is how do you get rid of the STOPPED daemons sitting around on your machine.  On my Mac machines I eventually wind up with hundreds of STOPPED daemons. Gradle needs a "--purge" command to get rid of these.

Comment: @Stevey Thanks for your comments. I have tried to figure out the issues. It will clarify everyone's concern what is actually happening underneath. We all know that removing `.gradle` folder can solve all issues. The intellect people also remove only 2 files version-wise `~/.gradle/daemon/5.5/registry.bin` and `~/.gradle/daemon/5.5/registry.bin.lock` for their solution. If there are multiple versions, need to remove multiple times.

Answer (score 29):

I solve it with another method in other post.
By removing folders like `4.4 4.6 5.4.1 5.5` in directory as below

> /users/[username]/.gradle/daemon

[java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58195187/7891350)

Comment: Which folder I can let if I deleted them.

Comment: Yes, deleting inside each folder under that .gradle makes the future builds clearer.

Comment: Windows 10 here. For me only solution was to remove everything inside `../.gradle/caches/`

Answer (score 6):

just reboot ur computer then go to .gradle folder and delete the daemon folder

Answer (score 3):

My problem solved only by changing gradle version from:

> App\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties
>
> > old: distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip
> > new: distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9-all.zip

Comment: This happend because a new folder is created in:

/users/[username]/.gradle/daemon

for each gradle version to store the deamons information. You changed to a new versión and a new folder was created, but the old one still is there with the busy threads.

Answer (score 2):

**For linux users**

**step 1** : `cd ~ && rm -rf .gradle`

**step 2** : `cd <to flutter working project directory>`

**step 3** : `flutter run -v` then kill process with `ctrl+c` .gradle dir will be created in `/home/<user>/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-<version>-all/9uukhhbclvbegdvsww0j0cr3p`

**step 4** : download gradle zip version on official website

**step 5** : copy and paste the downloaded gradle inside `/home/<user>/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-<version>-all/9uukhhbclvbegdvsww0j0cr3p`

**step 6** : run `flutter run -v`

**step 7** : everything is ok

Answer (score 0):

Just add two lines in your **app -> Gradle Scripts -> gradle properties**

```
org.gradle.daemon=true

org.gradle.parallel=true
```

Comment: how does it help?

Answer (score -3):

I created a new flutter project and migrated the previous data to the new folder, now it's working perfectly

Happy coding guys...