# Gradle error when building Android package

Tags: gradle, flutter

Recently I started getting errors when trying to build my android appbundle. It has worked fine before, and I am not aware of any change I have done.

```
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "/path-to-project/android/gradlew" exited
abnormally:
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
  Command: /path-to-project/android/gradlew app:properties


Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

When I run the script directly it says:

```
$ /path-to-project/android/gradlew app:properties
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details
```

And when I run it with `--status` it says:

```
$ /path-to-project/android/gradlew app:properties --status
   PID STATUS   INFO
  1573 IDLE     5.1.1
  2337 IDLE     5.1.1
```

I ran `flutter clean` but it didn't change anything.

Comment: plz check this topic here
[check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49074620/starting-a-gradle-daemon-1-busy-and-6-stopped-daemons-could-not-be-reused-use)

Comment: Thanks @WaelJlassi but I tried killing all gradle daemons and even restarted but it didn't help. When I start the process again, I get the same error message, which means that the newly spawned gradle daemon can not be used for some reason.