# evoking gradlew task produces never ending "....... Daemon, 1 busy Daemon could not be reused..." and add 1 to busy every line

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, gradlew

Sorry if the question title is not quality to say the least, But i am stumped at this point. Trying to update any project i have to  gradle-wrapper 6.5 and up produces a cascading.

This happens regardless of what task i run in terminal, or even importing the project into Eclipse.

```
C:\path\to\project\dir> ./gradlew eclipse
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip
.................................................................................................

Welcome to Gradle 6.5!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Experimental file-system watching
 - Improved version ordering
 - New samples

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
```

And of course each Daemon is creating a java process which will not stop unless the script is terminated. And then terminate each process manually.
[Task Manager Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYNQ6.png)

It does not occur on any other previous gradle version. Maybe someone here could point out the simple error i might have, anything honestly is a step forward at this point.

Comment: Does it happen on all tasks or only on `eclipse`?

Comment: any task, i should update thread to reflect that.

Comment: I'm also having this

Comment: Which command shell are you using?  (I see a forward slash in ./gradlew).  Does the same problem occur when running gradlew from cmd.exe ?

Answer (score 0):

As upgrade is mentioned, some options of a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49074620/starting-a-gradle-daemon-1-busy-and-6-stopped-daemons-could-not-be-reused-use) seem relevant.

`gradle --stop` should stop all daemons of your current version. Daemons of older versions are residing in an older folder. Deleting the old version folder should avoid what is described.

Relevant `gradle` [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/6.8.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:stopping_an_existing_daemon) has some details.

**Flutter**

I am unfamiliar with Flutter but the provided example looks to have been solved by this [pull request](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/95684) to read with [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/95533). It seems that some `gradle` properties are not set correctly.

Elsewhere, a `flutter.gradle` file is mentioned which I could not find in the repository. The `minSdkVersion` looks like the most important and it is read from flutter.minSdkVersion which might not be defined.

Comment: `gradle --stop` stops all daemons but then newer ones are launched, so it does not fix anything

Comment: Do you have older folder named 'daemons' or multiple gradle installations ?

Comment: no and I tested this on a CI so it's definetly nothing on my machine https://github.com/lattice0/flutter_bug/runs/6235250770?check_suite_focus=true