# Out of memory error: Java heap memory (GC heap)

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

Suddenly my app crash and pop this error out...any idea for this error ? tried so hard still can't solve...

`Clamp target GC heap from 111MB to 96MB
 Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 2.380ms total 71.136ms`

> Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 14710 byte allocation with 12888 free bytes and 12KB until OOM

```
AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
              java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 14710 byte allocation with 12888 free bytes and 12KB until OOM
                  at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
                  at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:125)
                  at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:278)
                  at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:123)
                  at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.flushLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:358)
                  at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.appendLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:303)
                  at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.write(FastPrintWriter.java:625)
                  at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.append(FastPrintWriter.java:658)
                  at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:691)
                  at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:31)
                  at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:324)
                  at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:300)
                  at android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(Log.java:509)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.Clog_e(RuntimeInit.java:59)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.access$200(RuntimeInit.java:43)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:91)
                  at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
                  at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

I've tried something like [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481178/how-to-force-garbage-collection-in-java) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32133013/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-on-android-1-4https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32133013/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-on-android-1-4), but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me to solve it? I really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: What does your code look like? Only post the relevant parts (code which gets executed when this error happens)

Comment: there is some problem with your code obviously. It is leaking memory likely.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: Note that your `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` occurred within `Throwable.printStackTrace`, read, while attempting to print another exception or error. That other throwable could also be an `OutOfMemoryError`, but it could also something else.

Comment: you are running out of memory. either reduce memory useage or check for memory leaks, recursive calls etc...

Answer (score 1):

In your `Manifext.xml` add this line `android:largeHeap="true"` it will allocate a large heap memory.

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"

        android:largeHeap="true"

        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme">
...
</application>
```

I hope this will work for you.

Try to use **Debugger and Android Profiler** to detect where exactly resources are used to improve the performance.

Comment: For future readers. This is not a solution, try to resolve the problem causing it