# Azure Devops Pipeline Task Cordova Build : Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources' (GC overhead limit exceeded)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, visual-studio-cordova

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources' (GC overhead limit exceeded)

It is an angular web app.With few pipeline task it has been Build according and through Cordova to get output of android.

In build pipeline ( Cordova 8.1.0) using for android.Pipeline Failed at this task every time

I tried all the possible research available.Please help me out.

Just for better understanding

```
 2020-05-05T09:12:42.1130739Z ##[section]Starting: Cordova Build android
2020-05-05T09:12:42.1258957Z ==============================================================================
2020-05-05T09:12:42.1259250Z Task         : Cordova Build
2020-05-05T09:12:42.1259571Z Description  : Build a hybrid app project based on the Cordova CLI, Ionic CLI, TACO CLI, or other Cordova-compliant CLI
2020-05-05T09:12:42.1259899Z Version      : 1.3.12
2020-05-05T09:12:42.1260099Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-05-05T09:12:42.1260422Z Help         : [More Information](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=691186)
2020-05-05T09:12:42.1260748Z ==============================================================================
2020-05-05T09:12:42.6440245Z Module cache at C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Roaming\taco_home\node_modules
2020-05-05T09:12:44.2264002Z Installing cordova@8.1.0 to C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Roaming\taco_home\node_modules\cordova\8.1.0. (This may take a few minutes.)
2020-05-05T09:13:05.9185740Z Exec complete.
2020-05-05T09:13:05.9186587Z npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
2020-05-05T09:13:05.9187177Z npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Roaming\taco_home\node_modules\cordova\8.1.0\package.json'
2020-05-05T09:13:05.9187710Z npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
2020-05-05T09:13:05.9188259Z npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Roaming\taco_home\node_modules\cordova\8.1.0\package.json'
2020-05-05T09:13:05.9188706Z npm WARN 8.1.0 No description
2020-05-05T09:13:05.9188980Z npm WARN 8.1.0 No repository field.
2020-05-05T09:13:05.9189296Z npm WARN 8.1.0 No README data
2020-05-05T09:13:05.9189561Z npm WARN 8.1.0 No license field.
2020-05-05T09:13:05.9189772Z 
2020-05-05T09:13:05.9189998Z + cordova@8.1.0
2020-05-05T09:13:05.9190308Z added 581 packages from 515 contributors and audited 1683 packages in 20.411s
2020-05-05T09:13:05.9190700Z found 20 vulnerabilities (8 low, 8 moderate, 4 high)
2020-05-05T09:13:05.9191036Z   run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
2020-05-05T09:13:05.9191281Z 
2020-05-05T09:13:08.3614893Z Adding ant.properties update hook
2020-05-05T09:13:11.3361244Z Module cache at C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Roaming\taco_home\node_modules
2020-05-05T09:13:12.8343971Z cordova@8.1.0 already installed.
2020-05-05T09:13:12.8344282Z Adding support plugin.
2020-05-05T09:13:23.3076454Z Platform android already added.
2020-05-05T09:13:23.3076980Z Queueing build for platform android w/options: --debug,--device,--gradleArg=--no-daemon,--storePassword=safeprofile123.,--alias=safeprofile,--password=safeprofile123.
2020-05-05T09:13:23.3320898Z Processing res/native for android
2020-05-05T09:13:23.8655211Z before_compile fired hook writeAntProperties
2020-05-05T09:13:23.8656385Z Writing property key.store.password to ant.properties, with value: safeprofile123.
2020-05-05T09:13:23.8657021Z Writing property key.alias to ant.properties, with value: safeprofile
2020-05-05T09:13:23.8657712Z Writing property key.alias.password to ant.properties, with value: safeprofile123.
2020-05-05T09:13:23.8658268Z Writing out config to D:\a\1\s\android\app\platforms\android\ant.properties.
2020-05-05T09:13:28.2824931Z Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
2020-05-05T09:13:28.2825845Z ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
2020-05-05T09:13:28.2826194Z ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk (DEPRECATED)
2020-05-05T09:13:35.6850083Z 
2020-05-05T09:13:35.6854697Z Welcome to Gradle 6.3!
2020-05-05T09:13:35.6855307Z 
2020-05-05T09:13:35.6855845Z Here are the highlights of this release:
2020-05-05T09:13:35.6856173Z  - Java 14 support
2020-05-05T09:13:35.6856382Z  - Improved error messages for unexpected failures
2020-05-05T09:13:35.6856556Z 
2020-05-05T09:13:35.6856762Z For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/release-notes.html
2020-05-05T09:13:35.6857124Z 
2020-05-05T09:13:39.3642934Z Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
2020-05-05T09:14:12.0818297Z > Task :wrapper
2020-05-05T09:14:12.1597969Z 
2020-05-05T09:14:12.1603316Z BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 43s
2020-05-05T09:14:12.1603537Z 1 actionable task: 1 executed
2020-05-05T09:14:12.3936221Z Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.3-all.zip
2020-05-05T09:14:20.5819569Z ...........10%...........20%...........30%...........40%............50%...........60%...........70%...........80%...........90%............100%
2020-05-05T09:14:34.3140609Z 
2020-05-05T09:14:34.3141503Z Welcome to Gradle 4.10.3!
2020-05-05T09:14:34.3141630Z 
2020-05-05T09:14:34.3141965Z Here are the highlights of this release:
2020-05-05T09:14:34.3142385Z  - Incremental Java compilation by default
2020-05-05T09:14:34.3142637Z  - Periodic Gradle caches cleanup
2020-05-05T09:14:34.3162741Z  - Gradle Kotlin DSL 1.0-RC6
2020-05-05T09:14:34.3163103Z  - Nested included builds
2020-05-05T09:14:34.3163546Z  - SNAPSHOT plugin versions in the `plugins {}` block
2020-05-05T09:14:34.3163712Z 
2020-05-05T09:14:34.3164313Z For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.3/release-notes.html
2020-05-05T09:14:34.3164700Z 
2020-05-05T09:16:59.3026926Z > Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
2020-05-05T09:16:59.3028166Z > Task :CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
2020-05-05T09:16:59.3030994Z > Task :CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
2020-05-05T09:16:59.4069501Z > Task :CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
2020-05-05T09:16:59.5011670Z > Task :CordovaLib:processDebugManifest
2020-05-05T09:17:29.5018843Z > Task :app:preDebugBuild
2020-05-05T09:18:00.3041874Z > Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
2020-05-05T09:18:00.3042647Z > Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
2020-05-05T09:18:00.3043133Z > Task :CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
2020-05-05T09:18:00.4246602Z > Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript
2020-05-05T09:18:00.4250125Z > Task :app:checkDebugManifest
2020-05-05T09:18:00.5075264Z > Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
2020-05-05T09:18:00.5075903Z > Task :app:prepareLintJar
2020-05-05T09:18:00.5076232Z > Task :app:generateDebugSources
2020-05-05T09:18:00.5991339Z > Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript
2020-05-05T09:18:00.5991664Z > Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig
2020-05-05T09:18:00.5992181Z > Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues
2020-05-05T09:18:00.5992595Z > Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugResources
2020-05-05T09:18:01.0063232Z > Task :CordovaLib:packageDebugResources
2020-05-05T09:18:31.0047099Z > Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugRFile
2020-05-05T09:18:44.9097078Z > Task :CordovaLib:prepareLintJar
2020-05-05T09:18:44.9097966Z > Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugSources
2020-05-05T09:18:44.9098360Z > Task :CordovaLib:javaPreCompileDebug
2020-05-05T09:18:53.7139560Z > Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
2020-05-05T09:18:53.7256090Z > Task :CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
2020-05-05T09:18:54.0848802Z > Task :CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug
2020-05-05T09:18:56.2082341Z > Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug
2020-05-05T09:18:56.2105179Z > Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug
2020-05-05T09:18:56.2105728Z > Task :app:generateDebugResValues
2020-05-05T09:18:56.2106211Z > Task :app:generateDebugResources
2020-05-05T09:19:05.1085388Z > Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
2020-05-05T09:19:05.1102047Z 20 actionable tasks: 20 executed
2020-05-05T09:19:05.1102743Z 
2020-05-05T09:19:05.1103066Z FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
2020-05-05T09:19:05.1103305Z 
2020-05-05T09:19:05.1103599Z * What went wrong:
2020-05-05T09:19:05.1104052Z Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
2020-05-05T09:19:05.1104612Z > GC overhead limit exceeded
2020-05-05T09:19:05.1105250Z 
2020-05-05T09:19:05.1105473Z * Try:
2020-05-05T09:19:05.1105874Z Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
2020-05-05T09:19:05.1106315Z 
2020-05-05T09:19:05.1107311Z * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
2020-05-05T09:19:05.1107548Z 
2020-05-05T09:19:05.1107839Z BUILD FAILED in 4m 52s
2020-05-05T09:19:05.1931384Z Removing ant.properties update hook
2020-05-05T09:19:05.1998074Z Error: D:\a\1\s\android\app\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2000408Z FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2019779Z 
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2023782Z * What went wrong:
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2094545Z Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2094968Z > GC overhead limit exceeded
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2095087Z 
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2095269Z * Try:
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2095750Z Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2096014Z 
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2096277Z * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2096413Z 
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2096536Z BUILD FAILED in 4m 52s
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2096867Z     at ChildProcess.whenDone (D:\a\1\s\android\app\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:135:23)
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2097190Z     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:310:20)
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2097497Z     at ChildProcess.cp.emit (D:\a\1\s\android\app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2097860Z     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2098126Z     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5) {
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2098342Z   stderr: '\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2098577Z     'FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2098750Z     '\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2098897Z     '* What went wrong:\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2099174Z     "Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.\r\n" +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2099408Z     '> GC overhead limit exceeded\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2099558Z     '\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2099749Z     '* Try:\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2100060Z     'Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2100364Z     '\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2100604Z     '* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2100958Z     '\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2101104Z     'BUILD FAILED in 4m 52s\r\n',
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2101417Z   stdout: 'Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.3-all.zip\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2101833Z     '...........10%...........20%...........30%...........40%............50%...........60%...........70%...........80%...........90%............100%\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2102188Z     '\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2102338Z     'Welcome to Gradle 4.10.3!\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2102488Z     '\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2102675Z     'Here are the highlights of this release:\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2102969Z     ' - Incremental Java compilation by default\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2103178Z     ' - Periodic Gradle caches cleanup\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2103370Z     ' - Gradle Kotlin DSL 1.0-RC6\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2103603Z     ' - Nested included builds\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2103815Z     ' - SNAPSHOT plugin versions in the `plugins {}` block\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2103999Z     '\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2104432Z     'For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.3/release-notes.html\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2105796Z     '\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2105969Z     '> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2106247Z     '> Task :CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2106924Z     '> Task :CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2107319Z     '> Task :CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2107793Z     '> Task :CordovaLib:processDebugManifest\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2108022Z     '> Task :app:preDebugBuild\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2108418Z     '> Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2108715Z     '> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2108960Z     '> Task :CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2109201Z     '> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2109458Z     '> Task :app:checkDebugManifest\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2109669Z     '> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2109872Z     '> Task :app:prepareLintJar\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2110120Z     '> Task :app:generateDebugSources\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2110344Z     '> Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2110655Z     '> Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2111129Z     '> Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2111381Z     '> Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugResources\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2111815Z     '> Task :CordovaLib:packageDebugResources\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2112117Z     '> Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugRFile\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2112359Z     '> Task :CordovaLib:prepareLintJar\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2112603Z     '> Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugSources\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2112910Z     '> Task :CordovaLib:javaPreCompileDebug\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2113169Z     '> Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2113441Z     '> Task :CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2113817Z     '> Task :CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2114117Z     '> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2114357Z     '> Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2114807Z     '> Task :app:generateDebugResValues\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2115183Z     '> Task :app:generateDebugResources\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2115399Z     '> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED\r\n' +
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2115715Z     '20 actionable tasks: 20 executed\r\n',
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2115879Z   code: 1
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2115980Z }
2020-05-05T09:19:05.2222161Z ##[error]Task failed
```

Comment: Firstly, try to set [javaMaxHeapSize in build.grade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32133013/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-on-android-1-4). Secondly, you can setup a self-hosted agent and run build on your agent [Self-hosted Windows agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops). On the other, you may provide a simple sample here.

Comment: What's the result after you trying it?