# Out of memory issue after updating buildToolsVersion '23.0.1' in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-build, build-tools

I am getting out of memory issue very often after updating `buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'` to `buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'` I am really confused and don't know how to solve this issue, since this error showing only with `buildTools` version `23.0.1`. Whereas it is working fine when I change it to `22.0.1`. Please help me. I am posting the error which I am getting as follows,

```
Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Add this to your android closure in your **build.gradle** file:

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

[Android Studio Google JAR file causing GC overhead limit exceeded error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25013638/android-studio-google-jar-causing-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-error)

Comment: I had the same issue, and this worked. But why did this issue occur?

Comment: @L. Swifter it appears that GC overhead limit exceeded . It seems like java needs more heap space than the default one.

Comment: same problem and solved on Android Studio 2.2 Beta 2 / Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 30):

The accepted answer works but I was confused for a bit about where to put the `dexOptions` in my `build.gradle`. We actually put it under the android section.

**Here is example snippet:**

```
android {

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    ......
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Actually for me worked a more complex solution, which combine all from above, plus enabling multidex in the **build.gradle** file for the module.

A. Add this line in the **defaultConfig** section to enable multiDex

```
// Enabling multidex support.
multiDexEnabled true
```

B. Than set the **dexOptions**, like this:

```
dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4G"
}
```

C. After changing to multidex and setting the heap to 4g, an overflow error may occur which lead me to uncomment and modify the jvmargs line from gradle.properties file of the project, like:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

The values may differ depending on your machine. You can also use double values.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to above procedure, there is another option to set jvm arguments.

```
org.gradle.jvmargs="-Xms2g -Xmx4g" in gradle.properties .
```

The setting is for tweaking memory. 
Xms: Starting memory
Xmx: Max memory

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem

1. go to "System"
2. Environmental Setting Adwanced
3. Edit _JAVA_OPTIONS values from  "-Xms1024m" to "-Xms2048m"
   (if not Exist _JAVA_OPTIONS  than create it click on New Button)
4. ok & save Restart

I think it will be helpfull for you also.
if it usefull upvote this answer.

Comment: Yes @Ali this is for Windows

Answer (score 1):

```
dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
```

I was facing the same issue by adding this in build.gradle file (module level) solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

use this in your app level build.gradle:

```
android {
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}
```