# what is the meaning of this error in message gradle and how solve it?

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-gradle-plugin

when run project I find this and can't solve this error but give this project to

my friend then run project he doesn't get this error help me of this problem

i want to solve this problem and what the meaning of this error

this my gradle :

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "done.ui"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

}

dependencies {
//compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.2.0'
compile 'com.pubnub:pubnub-android:3.7.4'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper:2.+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.5.5'
compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.0'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.github.kanytu:android-parallax-recyclerview:v1.4'
compile files('libs/PayPalAndroidSDK-2.11.2.jar')
}

repositories {
maven {
    url "https://jitpack.io"
}
}
```

message gradle consol:

```
 Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources,:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72200Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk420Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubClansFab155Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubKanytuAndroidParallaxRecyclerviewV14Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubKsoichiroAndroidObservablescrollview150Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:collectDebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
:app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex UP-TO-DATE
:app:shrinkDebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
:app:createDebugMainDexClassList UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\java.exe''finished with non-zero exit value 3

   Information:BUILD FAILED

   Information:Total time: 4 mins 57.153 secs

   Information:1 error

   Information:0 warnings

   Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25013638/android-studio-google-jar-causing-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-error/25013822#25013822

Answer (score 0):

Your `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` are `22` and you use `23.0.1` so change code with:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "done.ui"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.2.0'
compile 'com.pubnub:pubnub-android:3.7.4'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper:2.+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.5.5'
compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.0'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.github.kanytu:android-parallax-recyclerview:v1.4'
compile files('libs/PayPalAndroidSDK-2.11.2.jar')
}

repositories {
maven {
    url "https://jitpack.io"
}
}
```

Comment: can you explain meaning the error? @Michele Lacorte

Comment: I said Your compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion are 22 and you use 23.0.1, so you need to change it to 23