# Android Studio Error: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

After trying my hand at a bit of programming, I wanted to run my app on my phone only to encounter this error.

`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.`

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

I have absolutely no idea how to tackle it. I have googled the error, which led me to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25013638/android-studio-google-jar-causing-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-error). I tried the method and I still encounter the error above.

This is what my `Build.gradle` file looks like:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.peikle.peikle"
       minSdkVersion 15
       targetSdkVersion 23
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
    }
    dexOptions{
       javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
   }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.3'
}
```

I don't know what else to include to make the picture clearer but I'd be happy to do so on request.

Addition:

I have tried cleaning the project which unfortunately didn't work out like I'd hoped. Then I followed the links provided by g2o, and Ret and tried following the instructions there. This is what my build.gradle file looks like now:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.peikle.peikle"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions{
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
```

Now, I'm getting this error:

`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.`

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/parse/AbstractQueryController$1.class

It's a bit different from what I experienced before and I have no idea how to clean out this one.

Comment: try `build->clean project`  if that doesn't work the try `invalidate cache restart`

Comment: you could try to clean the project or use the help from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807587/com-android-build-transform-api-transformexception  and as a last possible resort, copy your classes and create a new project and repaste your classes

Comment: just check the answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/a/32811133/4848308

Comment: How about putting the error message into the title ?