# Android build.gradle issue

Tags: android

I have this build.gradle file :

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.---"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
}
```

When I build the gradle after loading I receive this error :

```
    Error:Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Error:2 errors; aborting
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the following into `android` of your `build.gradle`:

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

Also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25013638/android-studio-google-jar-causing-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-error) for further information.

Comment: Now the build grandle works but now i recive this error : http://prntscr.com/c1vt9c

Comment: That's another error. Try to update your AndroidSDK (Especially the GooglePlayServices). If this does not work, please ask a new question here so we can answer it specifically.

Comment: Also, if my answer solved your (asked) problem, please mark this answer as the correct solution.

Comment: 4G max heap size, is that not too much?

Comment: You could also use "2g" for example. Yes, "4g" is surely enough (if not over the top), I fully agree ;)

Answer (score 0):

Applications running on API Level 11+ can have android:largeHeap="true" on the  element in the manifest to request a larger-than-normal heap size, and getLargeMemoryClass() on ActivityManager will tell you how big that heap is. However: This only works on API Level 11+ (i.e., Honeycomb and beyond) There is no guarantee how large the large heap will be The user will perceive your large-heap request, because it will force their other apps out of RAM terminate other apps' processes to free up system RAM for use by your large heap Because of #3, and the fact that I expect that android:largeHeap will be abused, support for this may be abandoned in the future, or the user may be warned about this at install time (e.g., you will need to request a special permission for it) Presently, this feature is lightly documented

Answer (score 0):

look at gradle.properties file in project then you can see:

Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

## org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

You can change it to avoid out of memory