# android studio showing errors to R

Tags: android

In every project, there is a gradle error with R. R is red and build is failed. I haven't used any images in my project.

[error is like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYrVV.png)

My gradle is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R cannot be resolved - Android error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)

Comment: Have you made any changes to your application's package name recently? Sometimes, this can cause a problem if your R file has a different package name than your java file.

Comment: No, I haven't made any changes in my pkg name

Answer (score 0):

Either you might be having some issues with any of the xml files or you may import 'R' with your applications package name if you have resources.

Answer (score 0):

Add below lines in your build.gradle file:

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

[Android Studio Google JAR file causing GC overhead limit exceeded error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25013638/android-studio-google-jar-file-causing-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-error)

Comment: after adding this it is saying: Error:(25, 1) A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Addition'.
> Could not find method dexOptions() for arguments [build_3x5agyw9liwk00axdmp8pbnxs$_run_closure3@3b16563f] on root project 'Addition' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Answer (score 0):

Simply clean/rebuild the project and invalidate caches restart

Answer (score 0):

I think gradle is not importing all the packages remove the gradle and add new one with same version.