# Updated android studio version 2.3 not able to debug

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After update of android studio int 2.3 I am not able debug my application into my mobile while I can debug it into virtual machine.What would be the error?

My gradle error is here[This is the screen shot of my gradle result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrL8e.png)

And my App level gradle is here

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
   compileSdkVersion 23
   buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

   defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.example.application"
      minSdkVersion 14
      targetSdkVersion 23
      versionCode 60
      versionName "2.2.6.25"
      multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
 }
}




dependencies {
   compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
   compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0',
        'com.android.support:design:23.4.0',
        'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0',
        'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0',
        'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0',
        'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1')
  compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.9'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
  compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
 }
```

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25013638/android-studio-google-jar-file-causing-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this inside your `android` module level `gradle-build`

```
 dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```