# Android : I got an error while build APK

Tags: android, build, apk

I'm developing an android application, I got an error while build APK. the error message is showed in the picture. Thanks for helping

[click here for the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cOan.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your `app` / `build.gradle` file:

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

[GC overhead limit exceeded error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25013638/android-studio-google-jar-file-causing-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-error)

Comment: fortunately, i can build APK without error although i didn't edit the build.gradle. thanks for helping