# Error when trying to build APK

Tags: android, compiler-errors, apk

Okay, so I finally finished creating my first application that I spent a month building. And I went to build the APK so I can upload it to the Play Store and it hit me with this error.[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2utV.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Google JAR file causing GC overhead limit exceeded error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25013638/android-studio-google-jar-file-causing-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-error)

Answer (score 2):

check this answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25013822/5212133)

add this to `build.gradle`

```
dexOptions {
javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you've reached JVM maximum heap size.

Try add this to your app build.gradle file:

```
android {
    ...
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}
```