# How to solve the ionic build error "java heap space"?

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, ionic-framework

I have a ionic project. The app was build and run in my android phone successfully before. But suddenly from someday, when I run command "ionic cordova run android" I get the build error as below:

> Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

I have tried "cordova clean" to synchronise the cordova plugin. But it doesn't work..

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open `gradle.properties` under your project root directory and add/modify below line to

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx3536m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process. The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings. Change `-Xmx3536m` to **a larger value** if this still does not meet your requirement.

And, modify your **module level** `build.gradle`

```
android {
    ...
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I could not find gradle.properties.. where is it?

Comment: under your project root directory, there should be a project scope `gradle.properties` which only applies to your current project. If you don't have this file, you can just create it and add the line I said above.

Comment: Also, there is a **global** `gradle.properties` which is usually under your computer home directory, e.g. on macOS, it is under `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`, which is applicable to all your projects.

Comment: New error is:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx256M

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your build.gradle file-

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

also you could follow - 
[Android Studio Google JAR file causing GC overhead limit exceeded error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25013638/android-studio-google-jar-file-causing-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-error)