# i can't generate signed apk. I receive an error with these messages

Tags: android

I want to update my app, but when I try to generate a signed apk, I receive an error with these messages:

[image]

Comment: Check here about [build-error-java-heap-space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54623287/how-to-solve-the-ionic-build-error-java-heap-space/54623447#54623447)

Comment: Also, please post your error logs or source code in text instead of pictures or images.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve the ionic build error "java heap space"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54623287/how-to-solve-the-ionic-build-error-java-heap-space)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap. It currently has approximately 910 MB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090135/to-run-dex-in-process-the-gradle-daemon-needs-a-larger-heap-it-currently-has-a)

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your maximum memory allocation pool for a Java Virtual Machine.

You need to modify your gradle.properties file and increase the amount of memory allocated to the Gradle Daemon VM by 2 Gb, to a minimum of 4 Gb, using the org.gradle.jvmargs property: Kindly try as follows

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m
```

For more information please refer following link https://medium.com/google-developers/faster-android-studio-builds-with-dex-in-process-5988ed8aa37e