# Java Heap Space Error on Build in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

While project is building by cordova I get Java Heap Space Error. That error was started after when I installed AdmobFree and SocialSharing Plugings to project.

I tried increasing heap space with cmd commands but that didnt help me. 
Project looks like compiled successfully but I couldnt run on Android Studio.
I wish you can help me.
Regards

> cordova build android
>   Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
>   ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=D:\Android\android-sdk (recommended setting)
>   ANDROID_HOME=E:\AndroidSdks (DEPRECATED)
>   Subproject Path: CordovaLib
>   Subproject Path: app
>   Task :app:checkDebugClasspath UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
>   Task :CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:processDebugManifest
>   Task :app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:processDebugResources
>   Task :app:generateDebugSources
>   Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :CordovaLib:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :CordovaLib:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
>   Task :CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :CordovaLib:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:mergeDebugAssets
>   Task :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
>   Task :CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :CordovaLib:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :CordovaLib:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :CordovaLib:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:checkDebugLibraries UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:packageDebug
>   Task :app:packageDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.

  > Java heap space
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  46 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 42 up-to-date
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 1m 33s
C:\Users\Ertekin\Desktop\universitenothesaplama\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.

  > Java heap space
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 1m 33s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova build android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Comment: try like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54623447/10127727

Comment: unfrotunately it didnt help me

Comment: are you using --prod flag?

Comment: no, but i tried it now and anything didnt change.

Comment: I wrote
 dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
part to build.gradle that under the cordovalib folder and I updated gradle.properties. I cant find reason of that error

Comment: ANDROID_HOME=E:\AndroidSdks (DEPRECATED) .its showing deprecated

Comment: I could build project with it before. I started get that error after I added SocialSharing and AdmobFree plugins. I hadnt any problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem because of a very large assets folder. The folder included a SQLite DB that was about 1GB in size. For the build to succeed again, i had to change the

> platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js

and

> platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/StudioBuilder.js

- Replace the `args.push(’-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m’);` with a larger setting - I had to change it to `args.push(’-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx6144m’);`
- Make sure you are using a 64bit JDK version.