# Build failed Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: android, gradle, garbage-collection

after upgrading to Android Studio 3.4 and also with Anroid 3.4.1 i am facing an error when I try to build APK (normal run works) :
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
I tried all the suggested changes to gradle-properties withuot success.
It soccurs on task app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease
Any help would be appreciated :-)

Comment: What are the specifications of your system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution which is more easier than every other test / trick :-)
I removed the row "org.gradle.jvmargs=" from the gradle.properties in the project folder , but what did the magic was to remove it also from the file (under Windows) 
C:\Users[YOUR_USERNAME].gradle\gradle.properties

and everything start working as expect and faster than before :-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to increase heap size. Like said here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25013822/6041024

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
}
```

Comment: Hello, I tried almost everything and nothing seems to work :-(

Comment: Did you upgrade your Gradle as well?

Comment: yes i had but it didn't solved the issue, by the way I found how to fix it and I'll post it