# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.

Tags: java, android, android-studio, slidingmenu

I add SlidingMenu to my project(an empty project) and now I am getting an error when I try and run it. It builds fine but I get the error below when I run it:`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1`

Comment: check this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33901895/error-when-try-to-debug-my-app

Comment: Please show us your code