# Could not find method dexOptions() for argument

Tags: java, android

I am generating an app for testing but in the end it displays the error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded error.
To fix this issue I followed the solution on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25006075/extremely-long-build-with-gradle-android-studio/25006428#25006428).
And I have added this line of code in module build.gradle file

```
dexOptions{
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
}
```

But now it throws another error which says

```
Gradle sync failed: Could not find method dexOptions() for arguments [build_abwf3h5ru8za0j4597zvncj35$_run_closure2@30ed1096] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
        Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

Can you help me to fix this issue ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If your minSdkVersion is set to 21 or higher, all you need to do is set multiDexEnabled to true in your module-level build.gradle file, as shown here:

```
    android {
        defaultConfig {
            ...
            minSdkVersion 21 
            targetSdkVersion 25
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        ...
}
```

However, if your minSdkVersion is set to 20 or lower, then you must use the multidex support library as follows:

Modify the module-level build.gradle file to enable multidex and add the multidex library as a dependency, as shown here:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Depending on whether you override the Application class, perform one of the following:
If you do not override the Application class, edit your manifest file to set android:name in the  tag as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

If you do override the Application class, change it to extend MultiDexApplication (if possible) as follows:
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { ... }
Or if you do override the Application class but it's not possible to change the base class, then you can instead override the attachBaseContext() method and call MultiDex.install(this) to enable multidex:

```
public class MyApplication extends SomeOtherApplication {
  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
     super.attachBaseContext(context);
     Multidex.install(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: When I added the line android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" in manifest it throws error it the next activity line. I have a AppController file which I want to execute whenever I launch the app. So is it okay if I replace the android:name ?

Comment: create a class  like "MyApplication" and extends Application  class and  add "@Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
     super.attachBaseContext(context);
     Multidex.install(this);
  }"  and  <application
            android:name="MyApplication" >
        ...
    </application>

Comment: minSdkVersion is 15