# Gradle build is executing infinetly in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I recently installed the android studio 1.3.2.But my android studio gradle build is running infinitely. I followed all steps like Setting Gradle Build to offline, and HTTP Proxy in Android studio to No Proxy.
Followed the link

[Stack overflow link for android studio gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324849/android-studio-gradle-build-speed-up)

[image]

As seen in picture its executing infinitely . Your suggestions required. I couldn't able to work with android apps.

Help appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you try `File-> Invalidate Cache/Restart` of the IDE

Comment: I tried already. But invain.

Answer (score 0):

You should reinstall Android Studio. If you're using windows. Go to **Users** -> **[Your username]** -> **delete folder .gradle and .AndroidStudio1.3** -> **run AndroidStudio**, the AndroidStudio automatically re-config and download some required