# Android Studio is very slow - almost impossible to work

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm an Android developer. I have a Lenovo G510, running Windows 10 Home 32-bit, Intel Core i5 processor, 4 GB RAM, and Android Studio version 1.3.2 stable build. I've upgraded to windows 10 about a week after it's release. Before Windows 10, I had Windows 7. Already on Windows 7, Android Studio was very slow and took about 8 minutes to do a gradle build.

Except that, whenever the Android Studio is running on background, I can't open any other program. Not even Firefox, that doesn't uses that much RAM or processing.

When Android Studio isn't open, the computer works perfectly, but once I open it, the RAM consuming goes up to ~96%, and the computer starts to freeze and crawl.

So, is there anything I can do in order to make Android Studio run better and **not** to stuck my whole computer?

Note, I prefer not to spend money in order to speed it up.

Comment: Buy an SSD and increase the RAM.

Comment: I also recognized that AS slows down the processes. But 8 minutes is very long....however, I found some helpful tips here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324849/android-studio-gradle-build-speed-up

Comment: Android Studio doesn't work well with 4 GB RAM . So add 4 GB more RAM

Comment: I can run it with Visual Studio,See the screenshot [here](http://i.imgur.com/mrwH3R3.png?1).Try upgrading AS or switch to 64bit Windows.

Answer (score 0):

From the File menu there is an option - saving mode. It disables some background processes, including background code analysis. Maybe it's a little relieve the load.
In studio settings to disable code complete.
In the settings gradle write:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true  
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8   
org.gradle.parallel=true  
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```