# How to speed up work on Android Studio 2.0?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.0

I was waiting when Google makes the new `Android Studio 2.0 version`, because my project on `Android Studio 1.4` vers build and run my application in `1 min 35 sec` - its too long for me :(

But when I tried new version (2.0) I don't get speed up.
(`Gradle build finished with 2 warnings(s) in 1m 38s 534ms` - on AS 2.0)

So - how can I speed up for work Android Studio 2.0?

p.s. I have SSD, 8 Gb RAM, and Intel Core i3

Comment: Take a look at the suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324849/android-studio-gradle-build-speed-up

Comment: roght bottom there is a "sad man". click on it and make the indicator to the middle.

Comment: I found this article a while ago: http://kevinpelgrims.com/blog/2015/06/11/speeding-up-your-gradle-builds/. I was going to suggest SSD but seems you got one already. I should get one too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Instant run](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run) does speeds up a built apk, since it only updates changes. However, I think the speed of the first build is not improved.

Answer (score 1):

The speed of the first build has not increased in my machine too (8gb ram, i3, but no ssd), but subsequent build performance have increased from like 2-3mins(with multidex) to only a few seconds. You can increase the speed further if you use avd instead of real a device

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 2.1:

Click on Help --> Edit Custom VM Options

Click yes to create a new file if not created yet.

Then update the values with bigger ones according to your computer configuration, below is mine FYI:

```
-Xms1024m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

NOTE: Don't forget to restart Android Studio after the modification.