# How to fix Gradle take to much time to build app?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I need help in fixing this problem with Gradle build in Android Studio.

**I want to know what's wrong with  it..?**

Here is my System Config

[image: Here Is My System Config]

I am using: **Android studio 2.1.1** and **gradle-2.14.1**

My problem is that if I make just minor changes in project then it will take 5-10 min to build the projectagain.

I am also try  these settings :

gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

Here is Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.midmesolo.mindme"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

            }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.17'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.1.7'
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Takes too long time to run the app on real device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38004762/android-studio-takes-too-long-time-to-run-the-app-on-real-device)

Comment: can you post your build.gradle

Comment: How many and which dependencies do you have? Is instant run enabled?

Comment: result updated bro  see gradle build

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android studio Gradle build speed up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324849/android-studio-gradle-build-speed-up)

Comment: Are you so lazy you dont want to google?

Comment: Do you have an antivirus application running? Try if disabling boosts the build time and - if that is the case - add exception rules.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building and running app via Gradle and Android Studio is slower than via Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775197/building-and-running-app-via-gradle-and-android-studio-is-slower-than-via-eclips)

Answer (score -1):

Generally, gradle builds take some time, especially in Android.

You can find some useful articles regarding this issue on the Internet:

http://kevinpelgrims.com/blog/2015/06/11/speeding-up-your-gradle-builds/

https://www.timroes.de/2013/09/12/speed-up-gradle/

http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/making-gradle-builds-faster/

You can reducde build time by some margin, it's usually not a revolutionary change tho.

Comment: Link-only answers are bad here

Answer (score -1):

In my `build.gradle` I added this line. The number 2 means 2GB.

```
dexOptions {
     javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
}
```

Note: the value here is totally optional and situational. If you have higher RAM; you can dedicate the half of it. If you have less than then stick to the default value.

Comment: It increase the heap allocation of your Java so that it will a have a better processing speed.

Comment: Just paste in in your `build.gradle` before `dependencies { }`. Btw the order doesn't matter.

Comment: If he has low RAM this will crash his laptop

Comment: @AbAppletic he posted an image already that he has 4gb. Basically 2GB wont consume everything. Note: it is the developers responsibility to adjust that value, it inst compulsory to use 2gb value if the development machine is less than the capacity (You could go higher if you have better RAM size). I hope I do make sense and please justify the downvote.

Comment: Ok I guess its time for you to upgrade into 8Gb ram machine.