# How to Speed up Gradle build process in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am new on Android development and my Gradle build process tooks long time. Its annoying for me to wait for gradle build. Any Help is appriciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe the answers to this question help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324849/android-studio-gradle-build-speed-up?rq=1

Comment: what AS version are you using?

Comment: This link works https://hackernoon.com/speed-up-gradle-build-in-android-studio-80a5f74ac9ed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are some solutions I have mentioned:

**Technique #1**

1. Open up gradle.properties file
2. add the following line

org.gradle.daemon=true

**Technique #2**

1. Open up gradle.properties file
2. add the following line

   org.gradle.parallel=true

**Technique #3**

1. Open up gradle.properties file
2. add the following line

   org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

**Technique #4**
There are many other techniques for optimizing the speed of gradle build. If you are still having the problem I prefer you to use gradle from command line.
For more details, you can see a [discussion](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+RicardoAmaral/posts/e9PG6vSN5w3) on G+ with the developers about it.

Comment: Thanks Technique 4 worked best among these. Well it is satisfactory :)

Comment: For #3 make sure you analyze how much memory you have for your system. If you have 2g of memory only that will not be efficient for your system.

Comment: Yeah, 2 GB RAM is minimum requirement for Android Studio and 8 GB is recommended :). Less than 8GB will definitely run slower

Comment: can you explain what exactly techniques 1,2 and 3 do?

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest running all 3 of the techniques along with some android gradle plugin dexOptions too:

I have the following my **gradle.properties** file:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

I also have dexOptions in the **app/build.gradle** file too:

```
dexOptions {
  incremental true
  javaMaxHeapSize "4096M"
  jumboMode true
  maxProcessCount 8
  preDexLibraries false
  threadCount 8
}
```

You can tune those values for you system. Here is more information about those options:

**dexInProcess** - Whether to run the dx compiler as a separate process or inside the Gradle daemon JVM.

**javaMaxHeapSize** - Specifies the -Xmx value when calling dx. Example value is "2048m".

**jumboMode** - Enable jumbo mode in dx (--force-jumbo).

**maxProcessCount** - The maximum number of concurrent processes that can be used to dex. Defaults to 4.

**preDexLibraries** - Whether to pre-dex libraries. This can improve incremental builds, but clean builds may be slower.

**threadCount** - Number of threads to use when running dx. Defaults to 4.

Answer (score 0):

I just accidentally found how to build 2 times faster. May be it will be fix in the future, but now it works like clockwork. 
All you need to is hide your studio (cmd + H or cmd + R for mac, win + D for Windows).
I tested it with more then 100 builds for now (Android Studio 2.3), there were no exceptions.