# Android Studio keeps freezing even with new version of 2.2.3 for Windows

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-10, freeze

My Android studio was working fine in past few months but it started to freeze recently. I tried to uninstall and re-install the latest version 2.2.3 for Windows but it still keeps freezing and cannot be used. I've been searching around but could not find any solution. I am running Windows 10 and have 32GB RAM.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324849/android-studio-gradle-build-speed-up
https://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjrkozhgYbRAhUHMY8KHRL9A-wQFgghMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.viralandroid.com%2F2015%2F08%2Fhow-to-make-android-studio-fast.html&usg=AFQjCNH8F42hp45dFVky4VJPsk1n2ANOTQ&sig2=pc59CSuRI0--N9YrYJDgiQ

Comment: Same here. Also have more then enough RAM, happens in xml files a lot

Comment: Same here. Specially in xml files and line changing happens. I have 8 GB of RAM and I'm running on mac.

Comment: And same here. Have anyone find some kind of solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

If you have a lot of views in your layout file, try breaking your layout into separate files and use the `<include />` tag to reference them.

Comment: Even if you have tons of layouts that would still work with 32GB ram. Anyway, the question is from Dec 21. Current stable is 2.4 while the beta is 3.0b4. I dont think the answer is still valid

Comment: I  was experiencing this problem with the latest release as well