# Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution. Cause: Unknown command-line option '-,'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I start facing this problem in project building and then updated my Build tool and SDK. Removed all command line option from Android Studio's settings and still facing this problem. 
Please help.

Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution.
Cause:
Unknown command-line option '-,'.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after I entered the compile options found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38586477

```
--debug --stacktrace -a, --no-rebuild -q, --quiet --offline
```

From the docs as I understand it; the commas shouldn't be present and are just there to show that you can use either option - so -q or --quiet, not both.
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html