# Android Studio memory usage Ubuntu 16

Tags: android, memory, android-emulator, ubuntu-16.04, android-espresso

I'm facing an issue when consecutively running my android test class on an emulated device. I notice that after each run my PC RAM usage steadily increases by about 1.1Gb. This happens until my RAM is full, and then I have to restart my Android Studio and Emulator to run the test class smoothly again.

To investigate I looked at my system monitor. In it, my emulator and android studio maintain roughly constant RAM usage after each test class run.

[android studio and emulator RAM usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2uuj.png)

However my total RAM usage steadily increases after each test class run 
3.2 -> 4.3 -> 5.5 -> 6.7 Gb

On my emulated device I see that my app's maximum memory usage has only been 30mb

I have tried clearing memory after each run using `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` and this did not affect RAM usage.

I am running Android Studio 2.2.3 on Ubuntu 16.04. The emulated device I use is Android 7.0 API 24 running on Nexus 5, 1Gb RAM, started in terminal using AVD. The test class I'm running contains UI tests using Espresso.

UPDATE: This happens even when running empty espresso tests on an activity with a blank screen (no views). [Please find code here](https://github.com/LeroyChristopherDunn/Android-Studio-Memory-Issues-When-Running-UI-Tests)

Comment: i have the same problem in ubuntu. have you solved this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Android Studio needs to use high CPU because of Gradle and it's heavy tools.

Android Emulator needs high CPU too.Use Genymotion instead it.

Your Ram's Minimun must be 8 to run Android Studio fast.
If you have less RAM,It's too hard to work with Android Studio.
I have just 2.7 RAM and I'm forced to use unsupported Eclipse ADT.

To decrease RAM usage:

1-Make Gradle Offline

2-Disable plugins you don't need

3-And Many ways Here:

[Android Studio is slow (how to speed up)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817871/android-studio-is-slow-how-to-speed-up)

[Android studio Gradle build speed up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324849/android-studio-gradle-build-speed-up)

https://medium.com/@haydar_ai/easy-ways-to-speed-up-android-studio-2fafe1179b43

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. However it does not address the issue of Android Studio's increasing memory usage after running test classes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45314878/android-studio-excessive-memory-usage-when-running-espresso-ui-tests