# Android Studio Excessive Memory Usage When Running Espresso UI Tests

Tags: android, android-studio, memory, android-espresso

I notice that when running Espresso UI tests on an emulated device my system's memory usage increases indefinitely until I restart Android Studio and my emulated device.

On inspection I can see that my Android Studio and emulated device memory usage remain constant, yet overall memory usage increases. However I cannot see where the additional memory is assigned in my system monitor.

This happens even when running empty tests on a blank activity! [Please see code attached](https://github.com/LeroyChristopherDunn/Android-Studio-Memory-Issues-When-Running-UI-Tests)

I am running Android Studio 2.2.3 on Ubuntu 16.04. The emulated device I use is Android 7.0 API 24 running on Nexus 5, 1Gb RAM, started in terminal using AVD. The test class I'm running contains Espresso UI tests.