# Android Studio Excessive Memory Consumption without releasing

Tags: linux, android-studio, memory, gradle, linux-mint

I noticed that when doing builds with Android Studio my system's memory usage increases until I restart Android Studio.

Each build increases a little bit more up to the 16GB of my system. At the end I need to restart AS.

I am running Android Studio 3.0.1 on Linux Mint 18.1., 16GB RAM. 
I noticed this with and without emulator

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45226992/android-studio-memory-usage-ubuntu-16?noredirect=1&lq=1

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45314878/android-studio-excessive-memory-usage-when-running-espresso-ui-tests/49272797#49272797

Comment: did you find solution ?