# Android Studio 3.0 VERY VERY VERY slow on run

Tags: android-studio

I have a very big problem using Android Studio.

Every time I make a code changing, I have to check if all has gone well launching my app; but as soon as I click the "Run app" or the "Apply changes", it's the end: it starts the Gradle build process, which take even 30 minutes to complete, and furthermore Android Studio take the full control of my computer, not allowing to do nothing anymore (like open the browser, open notepad++, and so on...).

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Please give us your computer parameters. Android studio has minimal/recommended requirements to use it.

You have problems with all projects, or exceptional one?

Comment: On my hpone, a Samsung Galaxy S5; I'm making my first project; 4GB RAM - 64bit OS - Intel Core i5 6200U CPU, 2.3GHz

Comment: you need at least 16gb of ram with a i5.
But to run it a bit smoothly you need 32gb and a last gen i7 with a very fast SSD.
Both gradle and the Android plugin for intelliJ are probably the most inefficient software out there. But there is no other choice. Eclipse is not much better

Comment: 4 GB RAM development computer is too small. Ideally use 16 GB machine or minimum 8GB. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324849/android-studio-gradle-build-speed-up

Answer (score 1):

If you use Eclipse you won't have this problem anymore. but if you want to stick with android studio and gradle you can run your emulator and gradle once and whenever you want to compile your code run it on the already built gradle. this means that do not close the emulator and run your program on it again and again. this way you will not have to spent alot of time on loading the emulator and gradle

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio is not a very light software.It uses a lot of your system RAM and CPU power.So if you are using an old system then it is obvious that android studio will run slow.If possible then upgrade your system.
And one more thing it's better to use actual device rather than Virtual Emulator for our application working test.