# Android Studio compile linked libraries only when changed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I have a project in Android Studio which has two libraries linked. The Google Downloader and the Licencing library. Every time I want to run the app on a device it takes more than to 1 minute.

I have a gut feeling that the libraries are compiled every time, even if I haven't changed it.
Can anyone confirm this? And if it is so, is there anything I can do to speed up the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found another thread which describes the same issue. I might update Gradle etc.
[Building and running app via Gradle and Android Studio is slower than via Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775197/building-and-running-app-via-gradle-and-android-studio-is-slower-than-via-eclips)