# After Building and running in Android Studio the scroll and Android Studio working very slow

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Actually I'm working in `iMac`(OS X Yosemite, 2013) in Android Studio(v 1.1.0) I have open only one project, and when I run the app, after the app is running on my device Android Studio start to work very slow for around 1 or 2 minutes for example: scrolling very slow in a class, xml etc, while my app is still running on my device.

Is it possible the run to not affect this?

p.s I followed all the steps from this : [Building and running app via Gradle and Android Studio is slower than via Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775197/building-and-running-app-via-gradle-and-android-studio-is-slower-than-via-eclipse) and it didn't affect it.

This is my build.gradle file (app module):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId “com.example.example1”
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.2 2.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.2 2.jar')

    compile project(':library')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile project(':universal-image-loader-1.9.3')
    compile project(':simple-crop-image-lib')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally this problem is solved. 
If anyone is working a project which is synced via Subversion.
1) Go to Version Control and set None.[image]