# Android Studio avoid "make" while running

Tags: android-studio

When you press the run button in Android Studio the project is buit again, and as you know this always take long, if e.g. I select Build -> Make Project and then "Run" the make process runs again, I don't understand why? I would expect that it only installs the APK that is already generated. Is there a way I can achieve this, is my expectation funded or am I thinking wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the approach described here to speedup my build.

[Building and running app via Gradle and Android Studio is slower than via Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775197/building-and-running-app-via-gradle-and-android-studio-is-slower-than-via-eclips)

At the same time i've disabled "make project automatically" because sometime it produces old code.