# android studio 1.2 gradle is very slow

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

it's been a while that I'm using Android Studio, and up until now I was using 1.0.1, 
gradle was a bit slow, around 1.5 minute for assembleDebug (my project is really big!)
but today I updated my AS to 1.2 and now same process takes about 7 to 10 minutes, and sometimes even with no result!

is there any setting I have to change to make it faster ?
honestly taking 10 minute for every debug run is a nightmare !

Also most of the time, my cpu usage is arround 10 percent! (it is actually idle!)
cause before when gradle was working it was on 100% almost all the time

Comment: Apparently it got resolved in 1.2.1.1

Comment: how you solved it ...plzz share

Comment: @kumarkundan while Smashing's solution to make gradle offline is a good workaround, updating to 1.2.2 resolved my issue

Comment: Here is detailed post http://www.feelzdroid.com/2015/10/android-studio-gradle-build-speed-very-slow.html  on how to improve too slow Android studio.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/36826562/1770868

Answer (score 33, accepted):

had the same problem.

What I did was to change the global gradle settings to offline work which can be done by going to Preferences => Gradle. This did make a difference.

Another method I have seen people use, but which I have not used yet is to create a [gradle.properties](https://www.timroes.de/2013/09/12/speed-up-gradle/) in the gradle folder like so:

Just create a file named gradle.properties in the following directory:

```
/home/<username>/.gradle/ (Linux)
/Users/<username>/.gradle/ (Mac)
C:\Users\<username>\.gradle (Windows)
```

Add this line to the file:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
```

**Please check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775197/building-and-running-app-via-gradle-and-android-studio-is-slower-than-via-eclips/19500539#19500539) link for more options as well as a detailed explanation on speeding up gradle**.

Hope this helps!.

Comment: some how over time it got better, 
but I think it might be the effect of making it offline, since AS always uses daemon by default

Comment: This issue still happened with gradle 1.5.0. And indeed, putting gradle to work offline did speed up the compile time. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks that made 10x diffrence

Answer (score 11):

I was testing my app with Google+ log in. So I added release signing to debug version. App compiling in ~ 26 seconds.

**build.gradle** *Module:* *app* file

```
signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file(project.property("MyApp.signing"))
        storePassword project.property("MyApp.signing.password")
        keyAlias project.property("MyApp.signing.alias")
        keyPassword project.property("MyApp.signing.password")
    }
}
```

When I remove that ~ 7.5 seconds.

Next I tested offline grade

*File - Settings - Build, Execution... - Build Tools - Gradle -* **Offline work**

[image]

Now my app compiling in ~ 4.5 seconds.

Of course I also added turn on 
- Compile independent modules in parallel (may require larger heap size)
- Make project automatically (only works while not running / debugging)

*File - Settings - Build, Execution... - Compiler*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Complete answer for this issue is as below:

- Upgrade android studio to version 1.3(stable) or above 1.4(beta at the time of writing this).
- Upgrade gradle to 1.3.+(+ can be replaced with some positive number) change it in your `build.gradle` file.
- change your `gradle-wrapper.properties` files and add `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip` in last(you can remove any old entry).
- Go to `Preference` -> `Gradle` and set it to work offline.

woila!!! I am able to compile and run the code in less then ***~5 sec*** (**I really mean it**)

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be multiDex,

turn `multiDexEnabled` to **false** in your `build.gradle` file (for debug only, keep it for release).

```
android {
...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled false
        ...
    }
}
```

In addition you should consider to use the lastest version (2.4 at the moment) by editing the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file and set gradle-**2.4**-all.zip

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip
```

What is MultiDex : https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: Is there any other option to MultiDex in case you need it? I dont think apps are by default multidexed and setting multiDexEnabled false would make much of a difference.

Comment: turning off multidex is turning off features, not speeding up. there are projects which are bigger which would require multidex, so this is not helpful.

Comment: see my answer no need to do this

Comment: Thanks, you save my day..:)

Answer (score -5):

From settings go to HTTP connection and disable any proxy and you will find speed you want