# Android Studio too slow and laggy

Tags: android, performance, debugging, android-studio

Since I've installed android studio, it was never as fast as eclipse.
whenever I start debugging, it often takes 1-2 minutes start debugging and running app on my device.
**Question**: I want to know how can I resolve this issue (install windows 64-bit or install other type of android studion or ...)

My system configurations is like this:

- Laptop with Core i5 cpu,
- Windows 8.1 32 bit
- 3GB available RAM
- Android Studio 1.0.1 Build Feb 2015

And here is snapshots from my system status while running android studio:

**Task Manager**
[image: Task Manager]

**Bottom bar of android studio (Unhappy Guy!)**
[image: Memory Status]

and at last here is `studio.exe.vmoptions` content:

```
-server
-Xms512m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=760m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=

-Djna.debug_load=true
-Djna.debug_load.jna=true
-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio
-Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio
```

Comment: Are you sure it isn't related to Gradle ? Take a look here : Saved my day once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30024910/android-studio-1-2-gradle-is-very-slow

Comment: Get a faster machine, or go complain to Google about performance issues

Comment: the reason #1 is gradle. The reason #2 is 3 GB ram (too low. I have 8 GB, and it is not enough sometimes). the reason #3 is HDD(Do you have HDD or SSD? SSD is a bottleneck when working with gradle often)

Comment: AS doesn't "totally suck". You just need proper computers to run it, with enough RAM and maybe a decent SSD, not toys.

Comment: @VladMatvienko so do you know what is the 'unhappy man' icon means?

Comment: @VladMatvienko by the way what is this 'GRADLE' thing in android studio?

Comment: that's Inspector icon. Quick settings for language inspection. You can use google for most questions, like "what is gradle?", really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's be real about this: Android Studio, because it's based on java, has a ceiling to performance.  It's astounding how much faster XCode is, and pretty much any other IDE is compared to Eclipse/Android Studio.  It's popular b/c it's free.  This is the deal and many people are very price-sensitive.  Android studio folks are doing a masterful job, but they're handcuffed by java.

Comment: java is quite fast now.  JVM has been developed and enhanced for so long time, and very good now. It is true that it is not good  at native c/c++ ones, but very near now.  I can't believe you blame java for an application's slowness.  I developed eclipse plugin since ten years ago, working on system that is much bigger and complex than Android studio,  I never aware a performance issue because of java  itself, it's all because of bad design, bad algorithm, bad use of java and no qualified skills.

Comment: related to :" It's popular b/c it's free. This is the deal and many people are very price-sensitive. Android studio folks are doing a masterful job, but they're handcuffed by java"     a free product doesn't deserve to be good? Google didn't pay salary to these engineer who create it?

Comment: related to "Android studio folks are doing a masterful job", it's a job or you are from this team.

Comment: @BenXu, Still Java apps are isn't good performance than native apps. It's not good to develop large scale apps developed with Java. XCode didn't hanged yet in my computer but Android studio / emulator did always. It is eating huge RAM.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I go upgrade my RAM from 4 gb to 8 gb and it works fine

Comment: i cant upgrade RAM on win 32 :-(