# Running Gradle Build Very long

Tags: android, android-studio

everyone! 
After the latest update, the Studio has become a very long run (3-40min) "Running Gradle Build" before running the application. How is it treated? 
The current Studio version: 1.3.2

Comment: Check this post out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30024910/android-studio-1-2-gradle-is-very-slow/30025667#30025667

Comment: If you happen to use gradle wrapper 2.6 upgrade to 2.7 there is a known issue with 2.6

Comment: Run `./gradlew assemble --profile` so we can understand which task takes too much time. And, sometimes, run `./gradlew --stop` to restart the deamon.

Comment: upgrade to 2.7 not help(

Comment: After the update, the Studio began to receive a message:http://imgur.com/cOnHLlc Can proxy it?

Comment: reinstalled Studio and the SDK and it worked. But I don't understand - what was the problem...

Answer (score 3):

Firstly,

Allow Gradle to work offline **:** Go to **File** > **Settings** > **Build,Execution,Deployment** > **Build Tools** > **Gradle**. Then, in *Global Gradle Settings* tab, tick **Offline Work**.

Then, you can also tell Gradle to use a daemon : Just add `org.gradle.daemon=true` this line in the **gradle.properties** file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: gradle.properties in project folder?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in your `gradle.properties`

```
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms256m -Xmx1024m
```

`org.gradle.parallel` especially useful if your project consists of more than one project. Gradle will execute task in building these decoupled projects in parallel.

`org.gradle.daemon` no need to startup the daemon once it's up. Rebuilding will cut the "boot up" off. Thus, a faster build time.