# Gradle Build Running in Android Studio for too long

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Whenever I Start or run my project the gradle build running never stops.I have tried creating new project nothing is happening. Some projects are working fine but some of them are not and taking forever in gradle build running. Also whenever I open the project this cmd appt.exe file opens.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30024910/android-studio-1-2-gradle-is-very-slow/30025667#30025667

Comment: I have tried this but not working. Any other solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open the terminal tab and try building the project manually `gradle --stop clean build --stacktrace`

The `--stop` param will kill any running instances of the gradle daemon.  Its also possible gradle ran into a `.lock` file that is blocking its execution.  This can happen if a build is terminated before completion.  When you run on the command line it may take as long as 3 minutes before gradle gives up and fails.  The error message provided by `--stacktrace` should tell you where the file causing the problem is.

Just delete the lock file: `rm <pathToLockFile>` then rebuild.  This could happen a few times before the build completes.

It would be nice if there was a way to clean up all locks but to my knowledge this doesn't exist.

Comment: Only stopping the `gradle execution` from terminal didn't put an end to the process for me. I had to go all the way to `.\Android_Studio\gradle\gradle-2.10\bin` from command line and stop the gradle using `gradle --stop`