# gradle build uses 100% CPU and blocks UI

Tags: android, gradle

```
gradle clean assembleDebug
```

It takes around 2 minutes to build and it uses 100% CPU blocking everything until the build ends.
It happens from command line and from android studio as well. both installed version or gradle wrapper.

It's extremely frustrating. Need help.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30024910/android-studio-1-2-gradle-is-very-slow) didn't work

**Update**

**gradle version 2.7**

**gradlew version 2.8**

**android studio version 1.5.1**

Comment: Please say exactly which versions of Android Studio and Gradle you are using.  Also please say if you are using the gradle wrapper (gradlew) or some other standalone version of gradle.

Comment: You can't be using both gradle and gradlew at the same time.  gradlew will download the version of gradle mentioned in your .gradle directory.  Consider using *only* gradlew (recommended), and bump your gradlew version to 2.11.  There are lots of speed improvements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occoured during the execution of:

> transformClassesWithDexForDebug

Solved by adding

```
defaultConfig {
...
    multiDexEnabled true

}
```

to build.gradle

Comment: Wow this is so drastic. It may have fixed the issue, but it has other consequences; see here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33588459/what-is-android-multidex and see the official docs - https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html