# Why does building app in Android Studio take so long?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-build

I've been using Android Studio for the past few months, and I've noticed that it's a lot slower to build an app than Eclipse. For instance, in Eclipse, if I were to modify a line of code and then re-build, it would take less than 10 seconds. The same act in the same project in Android Studio causes the build process to last more than a minute (sometimes 2).  Is there any setting or configuration I can change to help with this? Is it gradle related?

Comment: I don't want to be that guy but .. this question does not belong in stackoverflow, it may belong to some other android-related site. Also I agree that Android Studio for some weird reason is becoming heavier, slower and not really easy to code, I use to code so much but now whenever i try to type a variable the whole program freezes for ~1 second so it can guess which variable i'm trying to type, personally i started using a terminal to build android projects, sure it has some disadvantages but at least i build a project within 5 seconds.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775197/building-and-running-app-via-gradle-and-android-studio-is-slower-than-via-eclips

Comment: am also waitin for the answer :)

Comment: @MartinKonecny i tried everything in that answer, even though it's taking about 50sec to build the apk. :( .

Comment: Yeah I tried everything in that answer, no luck.  The other weird thing is that I have an i7 machine, 16gb RAM, SSD drive, and when I go to build the app, the fan on that machine starts spinning like crazy really loud. I've never seen it worked this much.