# Android Studio and gradle 's slow build time, what to do in the mean time?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, compile-time

Hello to all my lovely Android Developer

I have been building android apps with Android Studio for around 8 months now, everything is great except that the build time with Gradle is SUPER SLOW, even tho there are options in gradle to speed things up a bit, it is still extremely slow if you were to ask me.

I am wondering what are everyone's solution to this problem and what is everyone doing during compile time?

Cheers have a good one

Comment: Android Studio with Gradle is very memory-intensive. A lot of people have problems if they're hitting swap heavily, which is super-slow. I would recommend 8 GB as a bare minimum, and 12-16 GB to be comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely makes a difference: https://www.timroes.de/2013/09/12/speed-up-gradle/

Just create a file named gradle.properties in the following directory:

```
/home/<username>/.gradle/ (Linux)
/Users/<username>/.gradle/ (Mac)
C:\Users\<username>\.gradle (Windows)
```

**Add this line to the file:**

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
```

[Building and running app via Gradle and Android Studio is slower than via Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775197/building-and-running-app-via-gradle-and-android-studio-is-slower-than-via-eclips/17286002#17286002)

Comment: I tried to edit this but SO wont let me.  the statement is "true" not "tru". you are missing the letter 'e' at the end.